# How can I insert multiple rows into oracle with a sequence value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that I can insert multiple rows using a single statement, if I use the syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle#39602).

However, one of the values I am inserting is taken from a sequence, i.e.

```
insert into TABLE_NAME
(COL1,COL2)
select MY_SEQ.nextval,'some value' from dual
union all
select MY_SEQ.nextval,'another value' from dual
;
```

If I try to run it, I get an ORA-02287 error. Is there any way around this, or should I just use a lot of INSERT statements?

EDIT:
If I have to specify column names for all other columns other than the sequence, I lose the original brevity, so it's just not worth it. In that case I'll just use multiple INSERT statements.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292199/query-several-nextval-from-sequence-in-one-satement if you got here and just want to select multiple different unique sequence nextval's in the same query...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This works:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME (COL1,COL2)
select my_seq.nextval, a
from
(SELECT 'SOME VALUE' as a FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'ANOTHER VALUE' FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: Getting the following error: `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`

Comment: @beckah ask a new question showing your SQL and Oracle version?

Comment: figured it out! structuring the inserted sequence value not as a query but simply as 'sequencer.nextval' as an insert value worked great :) @WW

Answer (score 24):

It does not work because sequence does not work in following scenarios:

- In a WHERE clause
- In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause
- In a DISTINCT clause
- Along with a UNION or INTERSECT or MINUS
- In a sub-query

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287

However this does work:

```
insert into table_name
            (col1, col2)
  select my_seq.nextval, inner_view.*
    from (select 'some value' someval
            from dual
          union all
          select 'another value' someval
            from dual) inner_view;
```

---

Try it out:

```
create table table_name(col1 varchar2(100), col2 varchar2(100));

create sequence vcert.my_seq
start with 1
increment by 1
minvalue 0;

select * from  table_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into TABLE_NAME
(COL1,COL2)
WITH
data AS
(
    select 'some value'    x from dual
    union all
    select 'another value' x from dual
)
SELECT my_seq.NEXTVAL, x 
FROM data
;
```

I think that is what you want, but i don't have access to oracle to test it right now.

Comment: What version of Oracle does that require?

Answer (score 3):

From [Oracle Wiki](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287), error 02287 is

> An ORA-02287 occurs when you use a sequence where it is not allowed.

Of the places where sequences **can't** be used, you seem to be trying:

> In a sub-query

So it seems you can't do multiples in the same statement.

The solution they offer is:

> If you want the sequence value to be inserted into the column 
>   for every row created, then create a before insert trigger and 
>   fetch the sequence value in the trigger and assign it to the column

Comment: I've done this before. It's a pain, but it seems to be about the only way around it.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to create a trigger on insert to add in the correct sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

this works and there is no need to use union all.

```
Insert into BARCODECHANGEHISTORY (IDENTIFIER,MESSAGETYPE,FORMERBARCODE,NEWBARCODE,REPLACEMENTDATETIME,OPERATORID,REASON)
select SEQ_BARCODECHANGEHISTORY.nextval, MESSAGETYPE, FORMERBARCODE, NEWBARCODE, REPLACEMENTDATETIME, OPERATORID, REASON
from (
  SELECT
    'BAR' MESSAGETYPE,
    '1234567890' FORMERBARCODE,
    '1234567899' NEWBARCODE,
    to_timestamp('20/07/12','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF') REPLACEMENTDATETIME,
    'PIMATD' OPERATORID,
    'CORRECTION' REASON
  FROM dual
);
```

Comment: really? How would you insert more than one row in a single statement without using union?