# creating and inserting data from a R dataframe to Cloudera Impala with DBI package

Tags: sql, r, cloudera, impala, r-dbi

I have created a couples of tables (data frames) in R that I need to upload to Cloudera Impala, I am using DBI package to connect with Impala. So I have for example:

df<-data.frame(x)

How do I insert df into Impala as a table?

I have seen that this is possible to do using dbSendUpdate(), so I have done something like this:

dbSendUpdate(dbh,paste0("Create Table db.df as select * from ",db))

but no luck.

Any idea on how to handle this issue with this function or any other function I could use for this?

Comment: Use `DBI::dbWriteTable` which runs the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instead use the function `dbCreateTable` or `dbWriteTable()` from the `DBI` package.

In your case, you can send `df` in the following:

```
data <- DBI::dbCreateTable(con, "impala_new_df", df)
```

Where `con` is your database connection, `"impala_new_df"` is the name of the new table desired in Impala, and `df` is the dataframe you are writing from.  You'll obviously need read/write access on your instance of Impala to do so.

I believe the `dbSendUpdate` function is from the package `RJDBC`.  Which will only work if your connection is `jdbc`, not `odbc`.  Also, I don't believe your use of `paste0` is going to behave the way you want it to.

Here's a useful reference on databases in R:
https://db.rstudio.com/odbc/

### Update

Since you ARE using `RJDBC`, I believe the following should work:

```
dbSendUpdate(con, "Create Table ?", df)
```

Similar to the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407579/6535514

If that doesn't work, I'd start looking into the package `implyr` for other ways around this

Comment: Yes you are right its from RJDBC package not DBI and I am using a jdbc connection. I have tried something like dbWriteTable(dbh,"db.mtcars"mtcars) but I get a syntax error from t

Comment: Yes, you are right its from RJDBC package not DBI and I am using a jdbc connection. I have tried something like dbWriteTable(dbh,"db.mtcars"mtcars) but I get a syntax error from the sql statement telling me that the use of DOUBLE PRECISION is not accepted. Impala does not accept the word Precision while creating a table, however dbWriteTable uses DOUBLE PRECISION as the default type. Is there any way to change this?