# Execute multiple INSERT statement in MyBatis for IBM DB2

Tags: java, spring, db2, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to execute multiple INSERT statement via MyBatis for IBM DB2 using Spring Boot (Java).

In XML

```
<insert id="insertIntoTempTmpCopyTo" parameterType="map">
   <foreach collection="list" item="lItem" separator=";">
      <foreach collection="data.keyList" item="rec" separator=";">
         <if test = "rec.sel and ((rec.keyType eq 'PPP'.toString())">
            INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(VP_ENCRP_PRC_RL_ID, PROC_CD, VER_KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_TP_CD, SET_INDEX_NUM, SET_MDK_DKI_NUM, PACKET_NUM)
            SELECT      
                '${lItem.EncrpRlId}' as ENCRP_RL_ID,
                '${rec.systemTo}' as PROC_CD,
                '${rec.keyType}' as KEY_SET_CD,
                '${rec.trnsltTpCd}' as TRNSLT_CD,
                '${rec.setTo}' as SET_INDEX,
                '${rec.dkiTo}' AS SET_NUM,

                <if test="lItem.packetNum != null">
                    ${lItem.packetNum} AS P_NUM
                </if>
                <if test="lItem.packetNum == null">
                    0 AS P_NUM
                </if>
            FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
        </if>
    </foreach>
  </foreach>
  ;
</insert>
```

Using this, I am able to create multiple insert statements

```
 INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(ENCRP_RL_ID, PROC_CD, KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_CD, SET_INDEX, SET_NUM, P_NUM) 
 SELECT '500137' as ENCRP_RL_ID, 'DB' as PROC_CD, 'MDK' as KEY_SET_CD, '0' as TRNSLT_CD, '1' as SET_INDEX, '001' AS SET_NUM, 766456 AS P_NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ; 

 INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(ENCRP_RL_ID, PROC_CD, KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_CD, SET_INDEX, SET_NUM, P_NUM) 
 SELECT '500137' as ENCRP_RL_ID, 'DB' as PROC_CD, 'MDK' as KEY_SET_CD, '0' as TRNSLT_CD, '2' as SET_INDEX, '002' AS SET_NUM, 766456 AS P_NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;
```

But when I am executing through Spring Boot JAVA , I am only able to insert one row

```
2019-05-24 09:36:51,094 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@123536e]
2019-05-24 09:36:51,094 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@123536e] from current transaction
2019-05-24 09:36:51,118 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] : ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(ENCRP_RL_ID, PROC_CD, KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_CD, SET_INDEX, SET_NUM, P_NUM) SELECT '500137' as ENCRP_RL_ID, 'DB' as PROC_CD, 'MDK' as KEY_SET_CD, '0' as TRNSLT_CD, '1' as SET_INDEX, '001' AS SET_NUM, 766456 AS P_NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ; INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(ENCRP_RL_ID, PROC_CD, KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_CD, SET_INDEX, SET_NUM, P_NUM) SELECT '500137' as ENCRP_RL_ID, 'DB' as PROC_CD, 'MDK' as KEY_SET_CD, '0' as TRNSLT_CD, '2' as SET_INDEX, '002' AS SET_NUM, 766456 AS P_NUM FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;
2019-05-24 09:36:51,118 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] : ==> Parameters: 
2019-05-24 09:36:51,158 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] : <==    Updates: 1
```

I am confused why is that happening. I am looking for a place to set allowMultipleQueries property to true, but I am not able to find. Is there any way I could set it during runtime.

Is that something I could do.

Any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify versions, but Db2 may support multi-row insert syntax.
There seems to be some variations according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743265/1261766), though.

I just tested the following syntax with Db2 LUW 11 and it worked.

```sql
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)
```

Using this syntax, the statement can be written as follows:

```xml
<insert id="insertIntoTempTmpCopyTo" parameterType="map">
  INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(VP_ENCRP_PRC_RL_ID,
    PROC_CD, VER_KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_TP_CD,
    SET_INDEX_NUM, SET_MDK_DKI_NUM, PACKET_NUM) VALUES
  <trim suffixOverrides=",">
    <foreach collection="list" item="lItem">
      <foreach collection="data.keyList" item="rec">
        <if test="rec.sel and (rec.keyType eq 'PPP'.toString())">
          (#{lItem.EncrpRlId}, #{rec.systemTo}, #{rec.keyType},
            #{rec.trnsltTpCd}, #{rec.setTo}, #{rec.dkiTo},
          <if test="lItem.packetNum != null">
            #{lItem.packetNum}
          </if>
          <if test="lItem.packetNum == null">
            0
          </if>
          ),
        </if>
      </foreach>
    </foreach>
  </trim>
</insert>
```

- The `<trim />` element removes the extra trailing comma.
- You should use `#{}` instead of `${}` whenever it is possible. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-).

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with IBM DB2, but you could change your mapper.xml to something like this

```
<insert id="insertIntoTempTmpCopyTo" parameterType="map">
    INSERT ALL  
    <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" >
        <foreach collection="data.keyList" item="rec">
            INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(VP_ENCRP_PRC_RL_ID, PROC_CD, VER_KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_TP_CD, SET_INDEX_NUM, SET_MDK_DKI_NUM, PACKET_NUM)
            VALUES
            (
                #{lItem.EncrpRlId},
                #{rec.systemTo},
                #{rec.keyType},
                #{rec.trnsltTpCd},
                #{rec.setTo},
                #{rec.dkiTo},
                <choose>
                    <when test="lItem.packetNum != null">
                        #{lItem.packetNum}
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        0
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            )
        </foreach>
    </foreach>
    SELECT * FROM dual
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

the `SELECT * FROM dual` at the end is very important

or you change your mapper.xml to

```
<insert id="insertIntoTempTmpCopyTo" parameterType="map">
    -- Change the delimiter from ';' to '§'
    -- @DELIMITER §

    -- removed separator=";"
    <foreach collection="list" item="lItem">

        -- removed separator=";"
        <foreach collection="data.keyList" item="rec">
            <if test = "rec.sel and ((rec.keyType eq 'PPP'.toString())">
                INSERT INTO SESSION.MP_COPYTO(VP_ENCRP_PRC_RL_ID, PROC_CD, VER_KEY_SET_CD, TRNSLT_TP_CD, SET_INDEX_NUM, SET_MDK_DKI_NUM, PACKET_NUM)
                SELECT      
                  #{lItem.EncrpRlId} AS ENCRP_RL_ID,
                  #{rec.systemTo}    AS PROC_CD,
                  #{rec.keyType}     AS KEY_SET_CD,
                  #{rec.trnsltTpCd}  AS TRNSLT_CD,
                  #{rec.setTo}       AS SET_INDEX,
                  #{rec.dkiTo}       AS SET_NUM,

                  <choose>
                      <when test="lItem.packetNum != null">
                          #{lItem.packetNum} AS P_NUM
                      </when>
                      <otherwise>
                          0  AS P_NUM
                      </otherwise>
                  </choose>
                  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

                  -- separator inserted
                  ;
            </if>
        </foreach>
    </foreach>
    -- Change the delimiter back to ';'
    -- @DELIMITER ;
</insert>
```

by changing mybatis-delimiter from `;` to something different, that doesnt appear in your statement, as `§`, you're able to execute semicolon-delimited sql-scripts