# db2 inserting multiple records returns [42601][-104] ILLEGAL SYMBOL ","

Tags: insert, db2

trying to execute an insert statement with multiple values clause. Receiving the error:

`[42601][-104] ILLEGAL SYMBOL ",". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: FOR <END-OF-STATEMENT> NOT ATOMIC. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14`

This is the statement:

```
insert into
    CLAIM_ITEM  (CLAIM_NBR,CLMS_ITEM_SEQ_NBR,ITEM_TYPE_CODE,ITEM_STAT_CODE,ADD_DATE,UPD_DATE_TIME,FOL_PROC_INDT,ITEM_CODE,ALT_ITEM_DESC)
values
    (479156072, 1, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TBC', 'Wood top black metal coff'),
    (479156072, 2, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TVBS', 'LG TV'),
    (479156072, 3, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'SOFA', 'Off White fabric sofa'),
    (479156072, 4, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'BDHQ', 'Q Grey HB master bedroom')
;
```

I did RTFM, and followed this example from IBM to the letter:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=statement-inserting-rows-using-values-clause

There are absolutely no errant commas anywhere (at least according to 'TFM').  What is particularly maddening is that the list of 'SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL' in the error message is blank, so even it can't tell me what it wants.

It works with one values list, but as soon as i add any more, it errors.

Leaving off the commas between value lists gives the same error, but then it lists ',' as an expected symbol.

This is driving me bat sh*t crazy.  Typical of IBM products though.  Follow the manual exactly and it invariably doesn't work for your situation.  And error messaging is totally unhelpful and cryptic.

I am using DataGrip, driver is com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver ver 4.26.14. These are determined by our db2 instance hosted by Ensono, (to which I have DataGrip pointing) so I have to go with it.

tried changing dialects from Z/os to LUW.  Neither work.

I am going to put this into my Java code anyway, and see if it works there.  Maybe (hopefully) it's just a DataGrip thing.

as stated above,
followed this example from IBM to the letter:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=statement-inserting-rows-using-values-clause

tried changing dialects from Z/os to LUW.

Tried one values list, which works.  As soon as I add any more (separated by commas), it errors.

Tried Leaving off the commas between value lists, but receive the same error, but then it lists ',' as an expected symbol.

UPDATE - further investigation revealed that we are on zos ver 12, which doesn't support this type of insert
(https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-insert)

however, this construct works:

```
insert into
UNITEST.CLAIM_ITEM
(CLAIM_NBR,CLMS_ITEM_SEQ_NBR,ITEM_TYPE_CODE,ITEM_STAT_CODE,ADD_DATE,UPD_DATE_TIME,FOL_PROC_INDT,ITEM_CODE,ALT_ITEM_DESC)
SELECT 479156072, 1, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TBC', 'Wood top black metal coff' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT 479156072, 2, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TVBS', 'LG TV' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT 479156072, 3, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'SOFA', 'Off White fabric sofa' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT 479156072, 4, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'BDHQ', 'Q Grey HB' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

similar stackoverflow post here:
[insert multiple rows into DB2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743265/insert-multiple-rows-into-db2-database)

Comment: You're using an old outdated manual for Db2 for IBM i.  Are you actually connecting to an Db2 on an IBM i?  If not, what platform and version of Db2 are you connecting to?

Comment: Note: your list of symbols that might be legal is ***NOT*** blank.  They are `FOR`, `<END-OF-STATEMENT>`,  `NOT ATOMIC.`   I assume this is not a stand-a-lone insert table.   Or your tooling is doing something you don't realize.  In other words, this is a tool issue as the statement is perfectly fine for Db2.

Comment: After checking into what our exact db2 version is,  found that we are on zos ver. 12, and this type of insert is not supported.  @charles,  yes, I did discover that those are the accepted values.  However, none of them help the situation.   I am posting an edit that shows more info and the eventual solution.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE - further investigation revealed that we are on zos ver 12, which doesn't support this type of insert (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-insert)

however, this construct works:

```
    insert into
    UNITEST.CLAIM_ITEM
    (CLAIM_NBR,CLMS_ITEM_SEQ_NBR,ITEM_TYPE_CODE,ITEM_STAT_CODE,ADD_DATE,UPD_DATE_TIME,FOL_PROC_INDT,ITEM_CODE,ALT_ITEM_DESC)
    SELECT 479156072, 1, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TBC', 'Wood top black metal coff' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 479156072, 2, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TVBS', 'LG TV' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 479156072, 3, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'SOFA', 'Off White fabric sofa' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 479156072, 4, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'BDHQ', 'Q Grey HB' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

similar stackoverflow post here:
[insert multiple rows into DB2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743265/insert-multiple-rows-into-db2-database)

Comment: Not used to ZOS's DB2 but maybe this form is possible `insert into
    CLAIM_ITEM  ...
with a as (
 values
    (479156072, 1, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TBC', 'Wood top black metal coff'),
    (479156072, 2, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'TVBS', 'LG TV'),
    (479156072, 3, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'SOFA', 'Off White fabric sofa'),
    (479156072, 4, 'C', 'REPT', '2023-08-14', '2023-08-14 23:20:59.436', ' ', 'BDHQ', 'Q Grey HB master bedroom')
)
select * from a
;`