# INSERT in a single column, the rest of the column will have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql

How to insert a default value in all columns after inserting a value in a single column,

Example: I created a `product` table and the columns are `id (autoincrement)`, `product_name`, and `item`.

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
    id int AUTOINCREMENT,
    product_name varchar(255),
    item int
);
```

How can I insert only the `product_name` and have the item automatically populated with the value `30`?

```
insert into 
    product 
values (
    'burger'
)
```

and have the result be

```
id: product_name:  item: 
7   burger         30
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801911/insert-multiple-rows-into-single-column. Please use the search feature before asking questions. This is easily found on Stack Overflow, and the rest of the internet.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's not a duplicate of that at all. He isn't asking to insert multiple rows.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree with Fluffeh; I don't see how that's a duplicate of this.'

Comment: Okay, but it shows how to insert into a single column. Wasn't that the point?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart, my point here is after you created a table, if i insert in only single row, the other rows should have a default value.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart and your link doesnt answers my question. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Default for item:

```
CREATE TABLE product ( id int AUTOINCREMENT, product_name varchar(255), item int DEFAULT 30);
```

Comment: so using the DEFAULT function will make the value of item as 30 each time i insert a new product name?

Comment: Exactly if you don't set a value for this column the default value will be inserted

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE product ( id int AUTOINCREMENT, product_name varchar(255), item int );
```

in mssql server use the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE product
ADD item int

CONSTRAINT DF_TestTable_NewCol DEFAULT 30 not null
GO
```

Comment: The tag however specifically asks for MySQL :(

Answer (score 0):

If your table has default or increment values, you can use either of the following syntax to insert the data and have it automatically fill the rest:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
id int AUTOINCREMENT,
product_name varchar(255),
item int
);
```

You have an automatic value for ID, but no defaults set for either of the other two:

```
insert into product (product_name, item) values ('Burger', 30);
```

OR

```
insert into product values(null, 'Burger', 30)
```

Now, if you set your table to have default columns like @cha suggested, you can enter in even less info:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
id int AUTOINCREMENT,
product_name varchar(255),
item int default 30
);
```

Allows you to:

```
insert into product (product_name) values ('Burger');
```

OR

```
insert into product values(null, 'Burger', null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Via phpMyAdmin, go to Structure for your table, click on Change for the item column. You can set the default value there by picking "As defined:" and entering the value.