# SQL insert multiple rows from query result into a single column of an existing table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to SQL and I'm struggling with the insert into function.
I'm using phpMyAdmin.

I'm trying to take a result of a query, a list (1 column)
and add it to a table with more than 1 column
with each result being a new row.

For context, I'm working with Olympics data.
I have a query that returns a list of countries that had athletes that competed but did not win any medals (country not found in "total medal" table).

```
-- Find Countries who entered and did not win medals
SELECT find.Country
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Country
    FROM `athletes`
    ) AS find
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Country
    FROM `total medals`
    ) AS inside
    ON find.Country = inside.Country
WHERE inside.Country IS NULL;
```

I am trying to add those 20ish countries to the 'total medals' table.
My assumption is that they would be added in with NULLS for every other column.

```
Country       Gold   Silver   Bronze   Total   Rank by Gold   Rank by Total
[result1]     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL           NULL
[result2]     NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL           NULL
[...etc]      NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL           NULL
```

The end goal would have the medal counts be changed to 0s and the Rank by Gold would be 87 and Rank by a Total of 78 for each row. I'm not sure if there would be a way to do that in one step as well, If not, I'm sure I could figure out changing a NULL to something else with.

```
[result1] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 87 & 78
[result2] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 87 & 78
[...etc]  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 87 & 78
```

There's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801911/insert-multiple-rows-into-single-column) that almost got me there, but it's missing the query result.

My understanding of this is that I should be able to plug my previous query into the values section.

```
INSERT INTO `total medals`(Country)
VALUES ([Query]);
```

But when I try that, I get a syntax error in line 4 (Select find.Country).

```
-- Find Countries who entered and did not win medals and add them to the medals table
INSERT INTO `total medals`(Country)
VALUES(
    SELECT find.Country
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Country
        FROM `athletes`
        ) AS find
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Country
        FROM `total medals`
        ) AS inside
        ON find.Country = inside.Country
    WHERE inside.Country IS NULL
    );
```

In conclusion:

1. How do I plug a query into a table with a different width
   2 Extra credit - can you also autofill the 0s 87, and 78 in one step?

Comment: what does your table look like? which db are you using?

Comment: @drum phpMyAdmin implies the OP is using MySQL or MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would phrase the logic using `NOT EXISTS` . . . at least to simplify it.  Then you would add the values for each row that you want.  Then you would add the values you want using `INSERT . .  . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO `total medals` (Country, Gold, Silver, Bronze, Total, Rank_by_Gold, Rank_By_Total)
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Country, 0, 0, 0, 87, 78
    FROM athletes a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM `total medals` tm
                      WHERE tm.Country = a.Country
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff Wonderful!
It seems that the `VALUES()` part was tripping it up.
I got it to work with my original query using your pointers

`-- Find Countries who entered and did not win medals then add them to "total medals"

INSERT INTO 'total medals' (Country, Gold, Silver, Bronze, Total, 'Rank by Gold', 'Rank by Total') -- replaced underscores with backticks (I should probably avoid spaces in column headers!)

SELECT find.Country, 0, 0, 0, 0, 87, 78 -- added the other values after the country calculations`

(cont.)

Comment: I had a question about your compact version as well.
1) I see you are aliasing "total medals" as "tm", and "athletes" as "a", but where is the "c" coming from in SELECT DISTINCT **c.Country**? Wouldn't I want the distinct athletes' countries ("a")?

2) I understand the front half, getting a distinct list of athlete's countries that don't show up in the subquery at the end, but the "1" is throwing me off a bit. Is that the index of the first column (Country)? When I tested just the subquery, it gave me a bunch of 1s.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @TheTravdrum . . . The `c` was a typo.