# SQL Server CE Insert multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-ce, c#-3.0

I am trying to insert into a SQL Server CE `.sdf` database file. I'm using these two commands, but I am getting an error when I am trying to insert it from C#:

```
INSERT INTO LazadaStaging (Id, TrackingNo, Flag) 
VALUES (5068652,'18111111293376', 0); 
INSERT INTO LazadaStaging (Id, TrackingNo, Flag) 
VALUES (5068642,'18111111293370', 0);
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance ;)

```
public void ExecuteCommand2(string commandText, CommandType commandType, SqlCeConnection sqlConn, SqlCeTransaction sqlTrans, params SqlCeParameter[] parameters)
{
    var command = new SqlCeCommand(commandText);
    command.Connection = sqlConn;
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    //command.CommandTimeout = 10000;

    if (sqlTrans != null) 
         command.Transaction = sqlTrans;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (command != null)
    {
        command.Dispose();
    }

    command = null;
}
```

Comment: INSERT INTO LazadaStaging (Id, TrackingNo, Flag) VALUES (5068652,'18111111293376', 0); INSERT INTO LazadaStaging (Id, TrackingNo, Flag) VALUES (5068642,'18111111293370', 0);

Comment: this command works in direct SQLCE but when i execute it inside C# it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the command:

```
INSERT INTO LazadaStaging (Id, TrackingNo, Flag)
select 5068652,'18111111293376', 0
union all
select 5068642,'18111111293370', 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been scratching my head for too long at this. 