# Writing continuous form data back to table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have continues form that is bound to a query (see query below). The query is the record source for my continuous form, and is non-updateable.

The query filters data down to provide a list of players that meet the minimum requirements, and those players are then displayed on the continuous form. The continuous form has additional controls for entering the GameID and the GameDate.

After adding the additional data I then need to write the records back to tbl_Bank. I did try an `INSERT INTO` but it only writes the first record.

INSERT statement:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Bank(GameDateID,GameID) VALUE (txt_GameDateID1,txt_GameID1);"
```

Query:

```
SELECT tbl_Bank.PlayerID, Sum(tbl_Bank.Change) AS SumOfChange
FROM tbl_Bank
WHERE (((tbl_Bank.DateChanged)<[forms]![frm_Navigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form].[txt_GameDate]))
GROUP BY tbl_Bank.PlayerID
HAVING (((Sum(tbl_Bank.Change))>=([Forms]![frm_Navigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![sfrm_GamePlayers].[Form]![txt_FinalPrice]*-1)));
```

Comment: refer back to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query) and you should find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Filter by Form?  If you have certain data you don't want the user to update, just disable those fields so they'll only be able to see them and not change them.

Check out this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304259