# Insert values from a list in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb6, sql-insert

I have a list with values in it. I want to insert these values in a SQL table using a single `INSERT` statement.

Example: Say, there is a list with names (the size of the list is not constant). There is a `STUDENTS` table with `NAME` column. I want to insert in the `STUDENTS` table the names from the list using a single `INSERT` statement.

Right now I loop through the list and insert the value in the table. That means, the number of insert statements is equal to the length of the list.

```
List<String> Name;
foreach (String s in Name)
{
  INSERT INTO STUDENTS (NAME) VALUES (s)
}
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this in a single SQL `INSERT` statement? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you need one string to be executed you can merge sql statements with ; like `INSERT INTO STUDENTS (NAME) VALUES (s1);INSERT INTO STUDENTS (NAME) VALUES (s2);INSERT INTO STUDENTS (NAME) VALUES (s3);INSERT INTO STUDENTS (NAME) VALUES (s4)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please update the tags with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MySql you can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl (f1,f2) VALUES(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)...(55,77);
```

For mssql dialect all the same

Comment: @DeanOC How can you forget the syntax? It is a "normal" INSERT statement with several VALUES blocks instead one. There is no much difference :D.

Comment: You can use this if you know the values that you are inserting (kind of hard-coding the values). In my case, the values live in a list, and the size of the list is not constant. So I cannot say VALUES ("A", "B).

Comment: but you can build string like this (1,2),.... in foreach cycle and after concat 2 strings in one statement, this was a question?)

Comment: @DeviSadhu You can use a StringBuilder for your query and append a VALUES block inside your for loop like this `sb.append("(" + s + ")");`. You just need to find a suitable way to add a `,` after each block. You may add it to the append and cut of the last one or you make an if statement for it.

Comment: @Tom I forget many things. I cannot even recall how many things I forget.

Comment: That sounds great. I can use a StringBuilder and create the string for  "VALUES(), (), ()" and then use that string in the INSERT statement. I'll try it out and let you know if it worked. As of now, I'll go ahead and accept this answer. Many thanks, guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

Union can be used to achieve this, though technically each union is it's own statement.

short demo:

```
create table #i(hello int)
insert into #i select 1 union all select 2
select * from #i
drop table #i
```

There are other / better ways of populating tables from lists...those depend on what database you are on.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a single `INSERT` is with a SELECT..  you'd have to convert your list into this:

```
INSERT STUDENTS(NAME)
SELECT 'Tom'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bill'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sarah'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list was in a temporary table, you could use the following syntax:

```
insert into tblname
    (columnlist)
select name from temptable;
```

Answer (score 0):

with string.join

> 

```
private void insertInto(string tablename, List<Values> list)
{
                                       
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($@"INSERT INTO {tablename}(number,comment) VALUES                                                   
                               {string.Join(',',list.ToArray().Select(r =>$" 
                               ({r.value},'{r.comment}')").ToList())}");
```

returns list data and result : VALUES(1,'hello'),(5,'hello2').....