# Error occurs: "Incorrect syntax near ' , ' "

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Insert Into Location 
                    ('Amman' , 'Sweleh' , 'Jordan') ,
                    ('Zarqa' , 'Hussen' , 'Jordan') ,
                    ('Jerash' , 'jenna' , 'Jordan') ,
                    ('Ajloun' , 'shajra' , 'Jordan'),
                    ('Irbid' , 'Hoson' , 'Jordan')  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error, you have missed `VALUES` keyword. If you want to omit the fieldname then try this:

```
INSERT INTO Location
VALUES 
      ('Amman' , 'Sweleh' , 'Jordan') ,
      ('Zarqa' , 'Hussen' , 'Jordan') ,
      ('Jerash' , 'jenna' , 'Jordan') ,
      ('Ajloun' , 'shajra' , 'Jordan'),
      ('Irbid' , 'Hoson' , 'Jordan');
```

Or use this format :

```
INSERT INTO table(column1,column2...)
VALUES (value1,value2,...),
       (value1,value2,...),
...
```

for more information read this **[mysql-insert-multiple-records](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)**

Comment: The syntax for inserting multiple records in SQL server (which is OP tag) happens to be the same with mySQL systax..However For precision matter it would be better if you provided a link for SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of an [INSERT STATEMENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement is:

```
insert into tableName (field1Name,...,FieldnName) values (value1,...,valuen)
```

Furthermore if you want to insert multipbe records in a singe query have a look at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: OP Query is somewhat correct but he missed `VALUES` keyword

Comment: Sorry I dont quite get what you mean..If he is missining values keyword then the syntax is wrong..

Comment: yes im not saying that query is right but he has missed VALUES keyword. Without adding fieldname also we can insert  the values

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax :

```
insert into tableName (field1Name) values (fieldNamevalue1)
```

Comment: OP has missed `VALUES` keyword.