# Error INSERT INTO MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

Learning PHP with MYSQL from w3schools. Everything is going fine but when i am trying to enter multiple value into table and it shows below error.

```
Error INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com')INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'm' at line 2
```

Here is my code Sample

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'envy';

// Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connected Successfully.".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com')";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com')";

if($conn->query($sql)==TRUE){
    $lastid = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New Record Created successfully. Last id: ". $lastid;
}else{
    die("Error ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error);
}

$conn->close();
```

As a beginner i don't where is the problem. I wrote the exact code like the tutorial but

Here is a link to the tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: For this query you need to use `multi_query()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Following code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

$sql .= ",('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com')";

$sql .= ",('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com')";
```

Comment: OP should adopt this unless multi query is supported.

Comment: This would be a better solution.

Comment: @RavindeReddy This is not multi query. This is batch operation and much faster than multi query .  Read this for further detail  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: Dont use w3shool its dangerous ly bad

Comment: @Dagon Dont overreact. W3schools is not dangerously bad.

Comment: @PareshThummar: I didn't say that solution in this answer is of multi query. And I am well aware of what multi query is.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a `;` between two sql statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com')";
```

Comment: This may fail if multi query is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Or instead of multiple queries, why not insert batches:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES 
        ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com'),
        ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com'),
        ('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com')
";
```

Answer (score 1):

While you run more queries, you need to end each one by semicolon.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com');";
                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Put semicolon(;) after each insert statement because you are executing more than one statement at a time

```
INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com');
INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Mary', 'Moe', 'mary@example.com');
INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('Julie', 'Dooley', 'julie@example.com');
```

Hope this works for you.