# Is it possible to insert multiple items to one row and get them back one by one

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, rows, table-valued-parameters

I am using this Sql command

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLES (reportno, samplename, analysisname) 
       VALUES (1, 'Lemon', 'ecobali1,ecobali2,ecobali3)
```

My structure will be :

```
REPORT NO : 1
   SAMPLE : LEMON

   ANALYSIS

   Ecobali1

   Ecobali2

   Ecobali3
```

Later on I need to get analysisnames one by one to enter details;

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLES WHERE reportno =1
```

My question is:

Is it possible to develop such a structure?

I am stuck here since I need to add multiple values to one row and get them one by one

Can I use TVP here and how?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

It is not a great practice to try to store multiple values in one row of your table. You should be just fine having a single set of values for each row because storage is cheap. If you want to have a single insert statement, you can insert multiple rows by adding to your `VALUES` clause. I found instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query) and have copied the example below:

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

Comment: first of thanks for the reply. My concern is here that how can I be sure that I am getting correct value after adding. I successfully added such data here ok. Later on I need to get value1 value2 one by one how I can I be sure that I am getting correct value

Comment: The point here is that your table structure is incorrect.  You need one table for the report and another, separate one for the analysis.  You might actually need more than that, but hopefully you get the general concept.

Comment: Yea, I guess I'm not understanding exactly what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Cory Let me try to prepare detailed structure and share with you . Do you have any mail address so I can share my expectation with you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your data in such flatted structure in a single table, but not in a good way.

1. Adding efforts to manipulate `analysisname`
2. Hard to analysis the data in SQL query

You should create a Master and Detail tables, in which the detail table store `analysisname`

Answer (score 0):

what i saw is, you should create another table named as `analysis`

```
analysis((primary)analysisID,analysisname,analysisdesc);
SAMPLES((primary)reportNo,samplename,analysisID(foreign));
```

this two table will create a relation `one sample with zero or more analysis`