# INSERT query needed for multiple rows

Tags: sql

How would I make a query to `INSERT` repeating data into several rows in a database? I have an auto incremented field id so I feel a simple

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column, column) 
VALUES ('data', 'data')
```

should be fine but not sure how to make it do it multiple times.

Comment: I am using MySql.  I've been using exactly the above query and, yes, expecting the addition of a rows with that information and the rest becomes NULL..which is what I want, but I want it to do that but more maybe the next 20 rows..I have looked at using INSERT ALL beforehand, but that gave me an syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common question, so I imagine more searching would've been beneficial. That said, a common syntax would be like the below, depending on which RDBMS you are using.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) 
VALUES ('data', 'data'), ('data', 'data'), ('data', 'data')
```

See other examples here:

[Inserting multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

[3 methods to insert multiple records](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/)

There is also the notion of bulk inserting, but again, not much information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how `MYSQLDUMP` does it.  The `VALUES` clause allows a list of one-or-more value sets to be provided.  A new row will be inserted for each.