# how to insert multiple dynamic row value into the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public void create(account_detail c, int jobcard_id)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source =(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Wattabyte Inc\Documents\CarInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            foreach (var details in c.Data)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into child_detail values ('" + jobcard_id + "','" + details.completed_by + "','" + details.reporting_time + "','" + details.cost_activity + "','" + details.spared_part_used + "');";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
```

I am using this code but it only taking single value but I want to save the multiple values into the database ?

Comment: Have you tried running this in debug mode to see the count of `c.Data`?

Comment: it only going one time..

Comment: If `details` in `c.Data` appears once, then it should only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
string additionalText = string.Empty;
bool needComma = false;

foreach (var details in c.Data)
{
    if (needComma)
        additionalText += ", ";
    else
        needComma = true;

    additionalText += "('" + jobcard_id + "','" + details.completed_by + "','" + details.reporting_time + "','" + details.cost_activity + "','" + details.spared_part_used + "')";
}

cmd.CommandText = "insert into child_detail values " + additionalText + ";";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Basic idea - prepare the string of teh command in the `foreach` loop, then execute the command once.

Comment: "insert into child_detail values (";   is this syntax error

Comment: Typo fixed (working according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query )

Comment: Take the code, swap the foreach loops, add the required variables, and you have it

Comment: string additionalText = string.Empty;
bool needComma = false;

foreach (var details in c.Data)
{
    if (needComma)
        additionalText += ", ";
    else
        needComma = true;

    additionalText += "('" + jobcard_id + "','" + details.completed_by + "','" + details.reporting_time + "','" + details.cost_activity + "','" + details.spared_part_used + "')";
}    its still taking one row value i cant able to find the solution please help me to find the solution

Comment: What is the count on `c.Data` ? (rows or length or something)

Comment: Then the issue is in the iteration. Look at the class of account_details, and find in MSDN the right attribute / method for iterating through the list.

Comment: this is my account detail
    public class account_detail
    { 
        public int jobcard_id { get; set; } 
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_job_card { get; set; 
        public String jobcard_preparedby { get; set; }
        public int estimate_prize { get; set; }
        public string expectedtime_detail { get; set; }
        public string compalin { get; set; }
        public int Carid { get; set; }
      
        public List<purchase_detail> Data { get; set; }
        public account_detail()
        {
            Data = new List<purchase_detail>();
        }

Comment: Please add this as additional data in the question, not a comment. **This should have been part of the question to begin with**

Comment: sir i tried many time but i am not able to get multiple values please help?