# how can insert array in database as one row with comma between each element

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert an array into a database in one row

```
    prod_id | user_id | quantity 
    1111    | 5       | 123
    1234    | 5       | 11
    234     | 5       | 1
```

if I have this table and want to select prod_id for each user and insert it into another table as

```
    prodid          qun        userid
    1111,1234,234   123,11,1     5
```

How I can get this result?

I try to use json but it returned an array and didn't store in the database.

```
<?php
    $sql = "select * from cart where userid=5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $prodid = $row['proid'];
    $qun = array($row['qun']);
    $prod[] = array('prodid' => $prodid);
    $quantity[]=array('$qun' => $data);
    }
    $quntatity= json_decode(json_encode($qun ));
    $products= json_decode(json_encode($prod));
    $sql = "insert into products( userid,products ,quantity) values('5',$products','$quntatity')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;


?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: use atleast MySQLi or PDO for safety

Comment: @SidiaStudios no i have user add more one product i want insert all product id in one row in database and when i want to retrieve it i can

Comment: <sigh /> Why do people insist on trying to use databases as though they were simply text files.... use a properly normalised database and it will be your friend.... try to store comma-separated values in a column instead, and it will hate you and do everything in its power to make your life difficult and miserable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GROUP_CONCAT to resolve like this

```
   $sql ="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(prodid SEPARATOR ', '),GROUP_CONCAT(quantity SEPARATOR ', '),userid
    FROM cart where Userid=5 GROUP BY userid;"
```

Comment: thanks it work probably but how i can to retrieve  it again to original