# php efficient read file and insert sql

Tags: php, mysql, file

**file: data.txt** (11617 lines)

```
   user  datetime
   23   2015-03-01 08:04:15 
   15   2015-05-01 08:05:20 
  105   2015-05-01 08:07:10 
   15   2015-06-01 08:08:29 
  105   2015-06-01 08:12:48
```

I only need data in 2015-06, I'm using fget and check each line's datetime but really slow, more than 50s.

```
    $d='data.txt';
    import($d);
    function import($d){
        $handle = fopen($d, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
        if ($handle) {
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
                $line=explode("\t",$buffer);
                if(date("Y-m",strtotime($line[1])=="2015-06"){
                   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` ....");
                }
                else{
                   //break? when month>6
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION:** less than 2s!!!! (thanks to Kevin P. and Dragon)

```
            if(substr($line[1],0,7)=="2015-06"){
               $sql.=empty($sql)?"":","."(`".$line[1]."`.........)";
            }
            elseif(substr($line[1],0,7)>"2015-06"){
               break;// when month>6
            }
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` ....".$sql);
```

Comment: for the date compare, just use `substr()` `if( substr($line[1],0,7)== "2015-06"){ ...`

Comment: @jpw: if it's a web application, making a user wait 50 seconds is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe insert multiple entries in to the DB at once instead of calling it every time you find a desired time?

In which case it's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: much much much more faster! less than 2s

Answer (score 2):

Can't be helped, use something faster than PHP. For instance, you can use `grep` or `awk` to read the file and filter it quickly. For example:

```
$lines = explode("\n", `awk '$2 ~ /^2015-06/ { print }' data.txt`);
```

EDIT: Also, `fgets` is not guaranteed to give you whole lines. You are getting 4096 bytes at a time; the boundary could be in the middle of a line, which will make the line not match if you are lucky, or break your code due to missed assumptions (such as the length of the `$line` array when constructing the SQL) if not.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>*) Or vice versa - it would be better for it to break completely, that is at least an obvious error yelling to be fixed; as opposed to silent data droppage.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use grep to filter out the lines you do not need.