# PHP Dynamic Query Creation from form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to be clever, possibly too clever in creating a set of forms that will dynamically insert their data into the database based on their input names.

I have it so it builds the query correctly, however when I attempt to insert it fails as to say it is a malformed query, is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve, but similarly?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="form_array['text']" /> 
    <button name="insert">Go</button>
</form>
```

Here is my query generation, on submit of the form:

```
$setup['table'] = "table1";

if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $inserts = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach($_POST['form_array'] as $form_id => $form_data){
        if(!empty($form_data)){
            if(!isset($first_run)){
                $first_run = 1;
                $inserts .= $form_id;
                $values .= "'".$form_data."'";
            } else {
                $inserts .= ", ".$form_id;
                $values .= ", '".$form_data."'";
            }
        } else {
            die('error');
        }
    }

    die("INSERT INTO '".$setup['table']."' ($inserts) VALUES ($values)");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very insecure script setup. You should research SQL Injection to find out why. To more directly address your question though... you have a syntax problem. Each set of values needs to be enclosed in parentheses like the answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: None of this is sanitized purposely, this is a test script and completely redacted. I am inserting one row, so all the values are to be comma separated within one set of brackets.

Comment: Ok then it is likely the fact that you are single quoting the table name. Remove those and you should be good. Unless you have perhaps redacted too much and changed the die call from what actually gets sent to the db.

Comment: I tried with and without, still the same: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''title', 'body', 'author_id') VALUES ('dsfeqf', 'sdwdwewe', '1')' at line 1** and I haven't redacted anything required.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the column names as well.

Comment: You must not put the table name or any of the column names in quotes. If you do so, MySQL will interpret them as literal values rather than identifiers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Can you post the sql query output?

Comment: suggest using an sql query builder (working with php objects), like [Dialect](https://github.com/foo123/Dialect) (ps author)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the fixes that was commented to you; this can be simplified, try it;

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="form_array[column1]" /> 
    <input type="text" name="form_array[column2]" /> 
    <button name="insert">Go</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $table = 'table';
    $handler = 'form_array';
    $keys = array_keys($_POST[$handler]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`".implode('`, `', $keys)."`) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $_POST[$handler])."')";
    echo $sql;
}
```

Output:

> INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')

Comment: The query seems to be still malformed from this unfortunately!

Comment: `array_values` seems kind of redundant there.

Comment: The keys seem to be given single quotes (') as well as (`), so it fails.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, you're correct, thanks! Danny, can you print your generated query here? It should only be backticked.