# Inserting values into the same column many times

Tags: mysql, sql

If I wanted to insert data into the same column multiple times as follows:

```
INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUE ('abcd');
INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUE ('xyz');
INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUE ('QRSTUV');
INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUE ('qrstuv');
INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUE ('12345');
```

Is there a more efficient way than the above of having to write identical inserts with the exception of the distinct data?

Comment: Perhaps reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html might help

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query
Couldn't find a button to mark as duplicate... Where can I find that functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT INTO string_tbl(vchar_fld) VALUES ('abcd'),('xyz'),('QRSTUV');`

Comment: Thanks! I should've known!