# Inserting multiple rows in a single Oracle SQL query:

Tags: sql, oracle

Inserting multiple rows in a single Oracle SQL query. Here is the following query I am trying to use. Can anyone tell me the error that I am having and how to go about it. Thanks.

```
INSERT ALL INTO 
     "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (
           COLOR, 
           PAUL, 
           JOHN, 
           TIM, 
           ERIC
     )VALUES (
           'White', 
           '1', 
           '5', 
           '1', 
           '3') 
     INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (
           COLOR, 
           PAUL, 
           JOHN, 
           TIM, 
           ERIC
    )VALUES (
           'Yello', 
           '8', 
           '4', 
           '3', 
           '5') 
    INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (
           COLOR, 
           PAUL, 
           JOHN, 
           TIM, 
           ERIC
    ) VALUES (
           'Black', 
           '2', 
           '2', 
           '9', 
           '1') 
    SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: insert into t1 select ... from ...

Comment: INSERT ALL
INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (COLOR, PAUL, JOHN, TIM, ERIC) VALUES ('White', '1', '5', '1', '3')
INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (COLOR, PAUL, JOHN, TIM, ERIC) VALUES ('Yello', '8', '4', '3', '5')
INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (COLOR, PAUL, JOHN, TIM, ERIC) VALUES ('Black', '2', '2', '9', '1')
SELECT * FROM dual;

Comment: what is the mistake in the above oracle sql query

Comment: It is traditional for a question to have, well, a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: Hi @Gopu, have you read this crucial page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? especially the part about searching beforehand you should.

Comment: Your table design seems messed up. Don't have one column per person, store their values in separate rows instead!!! Like (White, Paul, 1) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where close, but you have much to learn.

Here is how you could do it:

```
INSERT INTO "SCOTT"."GREATCOLOR1" (COLOR, PAUL, JOHN, TIM, ERIC)
          select 'White', '1', '5', '1', '3' from dual
union all select 'Yello', '8', '4', '3', '5' from dual
union all select 'Black', '2', '2', '9', '1' FROM dual
;
```