# SQL Server - Creating a table with a row of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of names I want to put into a temp/variable table but can not think of how to do it.

Here is a dummy list....

```
NAMES
McLovin
Deckard
Mufasa
DeLarge
```

This is a string I'll get sent to me which I need to wash against actual tables so I wanted to place this in a temp field but I just can not think of how to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE [#test] (
NAMES varchar (20));

INSERT INTO [#test] ([NAMES])
VALUES ('McLovin');

INSERT INTO [#test] ([NAMES])
VALUES ('Deckard');
```

The above is the only way I can think of doing it. I am new to SQL so am still learning the logic. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Also, You could have searched for multiple insert. no need to post duplicate dummy questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: If you are going to do it with straight sql instead of through an ETL tool, this is the way to go. I believe in SQL server you can do multiple values in your insert `INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('McLovin'), ('Deckard'), ('Mufasa');` Generally when I have a small list of values, I just drop them in excel and use string concatenation to build the inserts `="INSERT INTO [#test] VALUES ('" & A1 & "');"` then copy it down the rows.

Answer (score 2):

See This:
[Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

```
INSERT INTO #test ([NAMES])
VALUES ('McLovin'), ('Deckard'), ('Mufasa'), ('DeLarge')
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to Tedo's answer that you might not need a temporary table at all.  You can include these directly in a query:

```
select . . .
from (VALUES ('McLovin'), ('Deckard'), ('Mufasa'), ('DeLarge')) v(names)
```

Or use a CTE:

```
with names(name) as (
      select *
      from (VALUES ('McLovin'), ('Deckard'), ('Mufasa'), ('DeLarge'))
     )
select . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest on the fly way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 'McLovin') NAMES
INTO #temp
UNION
SELECT 'Deckard'
UNION
SELECT 'Mufasa'
UNION
SELECT 'DeLarge'
```

No need to write create statements too.