# Multiple inserts in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql

```
insert into fees (name, salary) 
values ('john', 155), ('katy', 300);
```

This sometimes throws an error

> missing right parenthesis

sometimes it is

> SQL statement not properly ended

if I use double quotes for name entries... What's the issue?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle for one does not support that syntax. And older SQL Server versions did not either. You should always post the **complete** and **exact** error message when asking for help.

Comment: What @a_horse_with_no_name said. The statement itself seems fine. Your problem must be lying elsewhere.

Comment: @Jens: the statement is not "fine" if she/he is using e.g. Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's why I started off with quoting your answer. As long as OP stayed within those constraints he should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to have multiple sql statements. For example:

```
INSERT INTO fees(name, salary) VALUES ('john', 155);
INSERT INTO fees(name, salary) VALUES ('katy', 300);
```

However, if you want to use the multiple-inserts-in-one-statement, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/452882/651174, and do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO fees(name, salary) VALUES ('john', 155), ('katy', 300);
```

What are you using to do the SQL insert if you're running into string-formatting issues?

Comment: im running from the cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

TRY This

```
INSERT INTO fees(name, salary) VALUES 
('john', 155),
('katy', 300);
```

Go to the below link for further information

[Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Comment: This is exactly the statement in the question which "gives an error"

Answer (score -1):

You can use UNION or UNION ALL

```
INSERT INTO fees(name, salary) 
select 'john', 155
union all
select 'katy', 300
```