# PHP SQL : Problems with insert multiple rows

Tags: php, sql

Based on [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query][1]) page, i have followed the answer on this page to adding multiple rows in sql, but not success.

UPDATE :

I forget to inform the problem :
**Only first row added success to db.** 
==> (idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, 71)

How to fix this?

```
mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO keg(idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, kdwil)
                                                        VALUES
                                                        ('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',71),
                                                        ('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',72);
                                                        ") or die(mysqli_error());
```

i am using PMA 3.2.4 & Sql Client 5.1.4.1

How to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: You missed a closing double quotes.

Comment: @frz3993 sorry, i hv upadte my code,

Comment: So, any error? Did you check the connection `$koneksi` is successful or not? And `mysqli` is for mysql, supposedly won't work with mssql.

Comment: @frz3993 sory for my missed, i forget to inform the problem : Only first row added success to db. ==> (idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, 71)

How to fix this?

Comment: Any field with unique, primary index? Because I see you're using the same variable to insert only differ by the `kdwil`. And I'm not sure, perhaps remove remove the semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use space between 'keg' and '(' as you using keg( . Rest seems OK accept if you forget to use " for ending. As I'm not seeing it here.

Comment: sory for my missed, i forget to inform the problem : Only first row added success to db. ==> (idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, 71)

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using same key value in your idkeg value or any of your unique column. If so then it will only take your first entry.

Answer (score 0):

**I Hope this helps!**

$query = "INSERT INTO keg (idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, kdwil) VALUES('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',71), ('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',72)";

```
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query);
if($result){
   echo "Your data has been inserted";
}
else{
 echo "Data insert Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if($koneksi->query("INSERT INTO keg (idkeg, nama, desk, tgl, kdwil) 
               VALUES 
                      ('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',71), 
                      ('$idkeg','$nama', '$desk', '$tgl',72)"
              )                                                             
   ){                                                        
   echo "Multi-INSERT failed: (".$koneksi->errno.")".$koneksi->error;)
}
```