# SQL : Insert or Update multiple row at one time with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To understand what I'd like to achieve, here is my problem :

- I have a list of "Place" in php array + sql table name "Place"
- Each "Place" can have one or multiple "Place_Box"
- Each "Place_Box" have (or not) some "Slot_Place_Box"
- This "Slot_Place_Box" have field "date", "hour", "slot_available"
- Now I have a list of "Date" + a list of "Hour" in some php arrays (some date have hour, other have not)
- I have a "Type" var in php ("1", "2" or "3")

What I want to do :

- I need to check if for each "Place", for each "date"/"hour" I already have a "Slot_Place_Box" in database :
- If YES : I update "slot_available" -> current data - Type
- If NO  : I create a new "Slot_Place_Box" -> date + hour + slot_available = 3 - type
- THEN : I have to get the last ID (the new I created or the one I updated) and create a new "Slot_config" data with this ID + an other ID I have in php var.

**Is it possible to achieve this in ONE Script/Request, using only MySQL and php?**
I just want to have few repetion and avoid to make request in php foreach loop...

- I saw this anwser to do the "update or insert" part : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)
- I saw this one for the "insert multiple row in one query" part : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

But I have doubt that I can combinate the two...I'd like to do something like this but I'm almost sure this is wrong and I will have to make at least one request by "Place" :

```
INSERT INTO Slot_Place_Box ( Date, Hour ) VALUES
    ( "2017-11-01", "23:00:00" )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Date = "2017-11-01", Hour = "23:00:00"
LEFT JOIN "Place_Box" as PB ON PB.id_place_box = Slot_Place_Box.id_place_box
INNER JOIN "Place" as P ON P.id_place = PB.id_place

@id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() or @id = (SELECT id FROM slot_place_box WHERE date = "2017-11-01" AND hour = "23:00:00"

INSERT INTO "Slot_config" (id_slot_pb, id_config) VALUES (@id, :id_config)
```

I hope my problem is clear enough to understand what I'd like to achieve, I'm beginner in SQL so **if you just have some "logic" to help me make my script it would be very nice** :)

## EDIT 1 :

After one more day working on this, this is how I think I will do it :

- I get every "id_place_box" according to my "Place" data
- Then I will create an array with all the combinaison possible of "id_place_box" / "date" / "hour"
- Then I will make a "SELECT" of all the "slot_place_box" where I can find a combination of id_place_box / date / hour -> I get "slot_available" + "id_slot_pb" value, then I UPDATE every result and keep the id's in an array.
- I now can make an INSERT IGNORE new "slot_place_box" with all the combination "id/date/hour" and add every new id to my id's array.
- Then I create a new "slot_config" foreach id in my array

I think it should works like this

## EDIT 2 :

I'm not sure I can do what I wanted to achieve (insert or update multiple row at once) for the following reason :

- I can't really UPDATE the "slot_available" field on "Slot_place_box" with some calcul, I need to get the current value, then find the new value according to my "type" value : I can't do

  ```
  INSERT INTO Slot_Place_Box ( id_place_box, Date, Hour ) VALUES
    ( :id_place_box_1, :date_1, :hour_1 ), 
    ( :id_place_box_2, :date_2, :hour_2 ), 
    ...
    ( :id_place_box_n, :date_n, :hour_n )n
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE slot_available = [some calcul]
  ```
- The other problem is that I can't get all the id's I UPDATED or INSERTED if I do all in one request. After each update or insert I need to keep the id somewhere.

Comment: Which dbms???????????????  Each of them has different syntax.  It's useless if someone provide a solution, but wrong dbms.

Comment: MySQL, I will edit my question :) I forgot, sorry !

Comment: Make you tag properly.  In this case the reference below is useless because it's for SQL Server.  It's a waste of everybody's time and effort.

Comment: My tag "sql" is for "sql language", the tag for SQL Server is "sql-server". So where I am wrong? I still add mysql for precision about the dbms

Comment: Before all you have was just a `sql` tag.  The answer that was deleted was for SQL Server.  My point is if you just tag `sql`, people don't know which dbms you use.  It's wasting everbody's time.  The answer he posted was useless for you because it won't work.  If you have put the `mysql` tag since the beginning, he wouldn't have posted that answer.  \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best solution but I got the result I wanted. I loop throught my array with "id_pb / date / hour" data and foreach row I create a new request :

```
foreach($SPB_data_array as $index => $SPB_data) {
    $current_id_pb = $SPB_data['id_pb'];
    $current_date  = $SPB_data['date'];

    if (!empty($SPB_data['hour'])) {
        $current_hour = $SPB_data['hour'];
        $sql_slot_pb .= 'INSERT INTO media.slot_place_box (id_place_box, date, hour)
                         VALUES ('. $current_id_pb .', \''. $current_date .'\', \''. $current_hour .'\')
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_slot_pb=id_slot_pb;
                         SET @id = (SELECT SPB.id_slot_pb FROM media.slot_place_box as SPB
                               WHERE SPB.id_place_box = '. $current_id_pb .' AND SPB.date = \''. $current_date .'\' AND SPB.hour = \''. $current_hour .'\');
                         INSERT INTO media.slot_config (id_config, id_slot_pb) VALUES (:new_config_id, @id);
                         ';
    } else {
        $sql_slot_pb .= 'INSERT INTO media.slot_place_box (id_place_box, date, hour)
                         VALUES ('. $current_id_pb .', \''. $current_date .'\', NULL)
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_slot_pb=id_slot_pb;
                         SET @id = (SELECT SPB.id_slot_pb FROM media.slot_place_box as SPB
                               WHERE SPB.id_place_box = '. $current_id_pb .' AND SPB.date = \''. $current_date .'\' AND SPB.hour IS NULL);
                         INSERT INTO media.slot_config (id_config, id_slot_pb) VALUES (:new_config_id, @id);
                         ';
    }
}
$sql_slot_pb = $bdd->prepare($sql_slot_pb);
$sql_slot_pb->bindParam(':new_config_id', $new_config_id);
$sql_slot_pb->execute();
```

I got the "$new_config_id" before when I create INSERT my config data then I made an SQL trigger to UPDATE the "slot_available" field :

```
CREATE DEFINER= ***** TRIGGER slot_config_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `slot_config` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @type_config = 
    (SELECT CC.type 
    FROM config_campaign   as CC
    INNER JOIN slot_config as SC ON SC.id_config = CC.id_config 
        AND SC.id_slot_pb = NEW.id_slot_pb
        AND SC.id_config = NEW.id_config
    );

IF @type_config = 1
    THEN SET @value_type = 3;
ELSE
    IF @type_config = 2
        THEN SET @value_type = 1.50;
    ELSE
        IF @type_config = 3
            THEN SET @value_type = 1.00;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF; 

SET @current_slot_available = 
    (SELECT SPB.slot_available
    FROM slot_place_box as SPB
    WHERE SPB.id_slot_pb = NEW.id_slot_pb
    ); 

UPDATE slot_place_box SET slot_available = (@current_slot_available - @value_type) WHERE id_slot_pb = NEW.id_slot_pb;
END
```