# GROUP BY a column in the same table to two alias columns

Tags: sql

I have this table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cijRy.png)

And I want to know if there is some SQL query to return something like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozgVO.png)

I tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT Object, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'A' THEN Qty END) As Key A, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'B' THEN Qty END) As Key B
FROM tab
```

And even added the GROUP BY clause but the error is at the CASE clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT Object,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'A' THEN Qty END) As KeyA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'B' THEN Qty END) As KeyB
FROM table  -- table won't work as a table name
GROUP BY object;
```

I added the `GROUP BY` and fixed the column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

add group by in your query as you execute the aggregation

```
    SELECT Object, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'A' THEN Qty END) As Key_A,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Key = 'B' THEN Qty END) As Key_B
    FROM table group by Object
```

you have used space of column alias name i changed it