# Insert multiple VALUES into table

Tags: fat-free-framework

I try to insert multiple VALUES into a table using the fat free frameworks sql mapper.

[Docs](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#parameterized-queries)

The problem is it only shows that for one VALUE

```
$db->exec('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?,?)',array(1=>5,2=>'Jim'))
```

As I have a lot of records and need to speed it up I wanted to add multiple

`VALUES`, as in VALUES(?,?),(?,?),?,?);

But how has the array to look then?

Background. I try to speed up the import this way because i parse big 100k+ csv files and import them.

Comment: The `VALUES` keyword should only appear once. See the correct SQL syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to do that is:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ('val1','val2'), ('val1','val2'), ('val1', 'val2')");
```

Definitely you want to use prepared statements, I recommend first to generate string for placeholders

```
VALUES (:q1, :q2), (:q3, :q4), (:q5, :q6)
```

and than generate bindings

```
[
   ':q1' => $data['val1'],
   ':q2' => $data['val2'],
   ':q3' => $data['val3'],
   ':q4' => $data['val4'],
   //...
],
```