# Multiple INSERT INTO statements not working in dbeaver

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert data into a table and I have written multiple `Insert Into` statements but I am facing an issue which is quite strange. When I run whole script, it gives me error that invalid character at the end of statement before semicolon but when I run each statement individually it works fine. There are thousands of rows to add and i cannot execute all individually. Any idea ?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "MFR"."NEWTABLE" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "Registry_ID" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "MFR_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "LIFECYCLE_PHASE" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "MANU_STATE" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "MANU_COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "POSTAL_CODE" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "PHONE" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "MANUFACTURER_LEGAL_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "ORIGINATOR" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SUPPLIERMFR_ID" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_OLD_NAME_1" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_OLD_NAME_2" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_OLD_NAME_3" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_OLD_NAME_4" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR), 
    "SE_MANUFACTURER_OLD_NAME_5" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

Sample Insert Statements:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE VALUES ('PESSIL DEVELOPMENT LIMITED','3008','Manufacturer','Approved','Hopewell Industrial city ,Sima,Changping','Dongguan',NULL,NULL,'N/A','86-769-3391096','PESSIL DEVELOPMENT LIMITED','Julia Yang','PP13630',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); 
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE VALUES ('MING TONG','3013','Manufacturer','Approved','No. 10 Yang Shi Metal Sueface processing Industrial Park ,','Wu Xi',NULL,NULL,'214154','0136-5617-8698','MING TONG BIAU SHENG CO.,LTD','Jamie Wang','SS01111',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); 
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE VALUES ('LI TENG ENTERPRISE CO LTD','3012','Manufacturer','Approved','No. 49-22, 5 Lin, Tai-Ho-Tsuen','Ju-Bai',NULL,NULL,'302','N/A','LI TENG ENTERPRISE CO LTD',NULL,'PP01130',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); 
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE VALUES ('PANASONIC','3004','Manufacturer','Approved','10th Fi.,National No. 6, Bldg.,1-1-30,Shibadaimon,Minato-ku,','Minato-ku',NULL,NULL,'105-8586','81-3-54728222','PANASONIC GOBEL ELECTRONIC COMPONENTS',NULL,'SS00360','Panasonic',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); 
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE VALUES ('PROSOFT SCITECHNOLOGY','3009','Manufacturer','Disqualified','# 8,Caitang Industry Park, Lvling Road, Huli District, 
Xiamen, Fujian 361009, China','XiaMen',NULL,NULL,'N/A','86-592-59057000-206','PROSOFT SCITECHNOLOGY (XIAMEN)CO.,LTD.','Anny Chen','PP16140',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I am using dbeaver for my sql operations. Database is Oracle

Comment: What method are you using to execute the statements?  Based on https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1650, I suspect you need to run as a script (Alt-X).

Comment: Certainly there is nothing wrong in your SQL statements. Something wrong the way it's being executed.

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of script ? Can you use any example please ?

Comment: NVM, figured it out. Thanks. I have to press Alt+X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same issue, in case you don't see the comment, you have to "execute the script" from the menu or with `alt+x` and not just the query.

Answer (score 2):

separate values with commas

`INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`

the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/705678/11214262

Comment: He's using Oracle database and your solution is "just" valid to MySQL, SQL Server...