# Insert multiple rows in a single query using results of a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert, sql-server-2016

I am looking for a compact way to do this - insert multiple rows into a table with values from multiple columns of a row from another table. My destination table is really a list with a single column:

```
declare @stringList table
(
    val nvarchar(100)
)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query) is how we can insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO @stringList ( val ) VALUES
Val1, Val2, Val3, ...
```

This is how we insert from a select:

```
INSERT INTO @stringList 
SELECT col1 FROM table1 where id=something
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to use both at the same time.

I can select from one column:

```
insert into @stringList (val) 
select col1 from table1 where id=something
```

But it doesn't extend to multiple columns:

```
insert into @stringList (val) 
select col1, col2 from table1 where id=something

--The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
```

I have tried various ways including using parentheses, but the syntax is not accepted:

```
insert into @stringList (val) 
(select col1 from table1 where id=something,
select  col2 from table1 where id=something
```

Any idea if what I want is doable?

Comment: You can use a cursor to get row level data from one table and insert into another table by using a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot using `cross apply`:

```
insert into @stringList (val) 
    select v.col
    from table1 t1 cross apply
         (values (t1.col1), (t1.col2)) v(col)
    where t1.id = something;
```

Comment: My mind is blown.  I did not know you could use *values* that way.  So many wasted unions...

Comment: @DanielGimenez . . . This is also more efficient.