# How can i solve a sql nested query problem

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

```
    Dim Cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO feesPayments VALUES('" 
            & Fees_Payments_Dashboard.txtAmountTendered.Text & "','" 
            & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & "', 'studentID' ,'" 
            & Fees_Payments_Dashboard.selectTerm.SelectedItem & "','" 
            & Facility & "','" 
            & Fees_Payments_Dashboard.selectPaymentMethod.Text 
            & "'studentID = SELECT students.studentID 
                            FROM students WHERE 
                            name='" & Fees_Payments_Dashboard.txtName.Text 
                               & "' AND surname='" & Fees_Payments_Dashboard.txtSurname.Text 
                               & "')  ", Conn)
   Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: What is your "problem"? Which dmbs do you use? Have you read [ask]?

Comment: i use sql. The problem is , i have two tables right and i want to insert data in my payments table but one of the column is in the other table. the tables are Students and Payments in which i want to select only the studentsID from the students table and insert it into the payments where studentID is the foreign key

Comment: Is there an error ... if so, what is the error message?

Comment: You are wide open to sql injection. **Always use parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO feesPayments VALUES('Fees_Payments_Dashboard.txtAmountTendered.Text',
                                'Date.Now.ToShortDateString', 
                                'studentID' ,'Fees_Payments_Dashboard.selectTerm.SelectedItem',
                                'Facility','Fees_Payments_Dashboard.selectPaymentMethod.Text'
```

I have not seen syntax for a SQL query written this way before so I apologize if I'm incorrect, but it appears this statement will insert the string value 'studentID' instead of the value held in a parameter called studentID.

I am not sure how your ending portion is supposed to work syntactically either.

Generally, inserts are single rows although they can be multiple like so:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
VALUES
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
```

Source: [Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

But even with that, it doesn't match how you are attempting.

If you want to insert a brand new row into feesPayments based on some condition, I recommned writing a loop based on that condition in your code base, so that it can call the insert in each loop. Therefore, allowing a simple insert with the values you need.

We will need more information about what you are trying to accomplish though, because it's not very clear based on what you provided.