# How can I add a lot of new values into an existing table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table of airports containing the following columns: **ID, Name, Country**. I´ve already inserted values to those columns and have almost 100 rows. But now I need to add a new column for airport codes called **Code** and add values to each row. I already created that new column, but since I have so many rows in that table, I´m really confused how could I add values for that column to those data fields. Each row has a different value for Code column. Is the only way to do it as following:

```
update Airports
set Code = 'BCN'
where id = 1
```

Should I really use the similar code for every row in the table? It´s almost 100 times. Or is there any other way? Should I maybe insert airport codes into Excel table and then import these into my SQL table? I started to learn SQL just recently, so I´m really thankful for any help!
Thank You!

Comment: There are a few ways to do this.  A straight forward way can be to auto-generate a .sql file (through Python for example) which writes `update Airports set Code = ‘AAA’ where id = N;` for as many entries as you have to add.  Generally, repeated code such as this is discouraged, however SQL is a different beast, and it’s considered acceptable.  Another way, (if you have access to Python (or the like)) would be to dynamically generate the statement in a loop, and execute each UPDATE statement in turn. (I like the script approach, because there’s a hard copy which can be reused and archived.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming you have to manually assign a new code to each record in your Airport table and you have the ability to import an Excel/CSV file into a table. It may be easier to just create a Excel/CSV file containing all your columns/rows of data, truncate the existing table and re-import the data. 

Another option is to re-generate the data with a SQL script by using INSERT with many values. Here's an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: Aside: here is a link to Wiki’s [IATA codes table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_airport_code:_A), which might be useful in your project.

Comment: Can throw a demo (answer) together for you.  However, will need to know 1) what does your source data look like, 2) which database engine are you running,  3) what other tools you have access to, (Python?) and 4) which OS?  Please update the question with these specifics.

Comment: So where does this list of codes come from? If you only have 100 rows then just re-insert the data including the code

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
This project is for my beginner´s SQL course. So I inserted data manually. I´m using T-SQL (Transact-SQL) and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Unfortunately I haven´t learned Python or other programming languages yet. I just started with „SQL for beginners“ recently.  And I´m using Windows OS.

Comment: If you have id and code rhen create a temp table and update the main table with a join to the temp table

Comment: Maybe a joined update using either a temp table or a `VALUES` virtual table.