# Inserting multiple rows into Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

In the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle#39602) about multiple row insert into the Oracle two approaches were demonstrated:

First:

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
          select 8000,0,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
union all select 8001,0,'Multi 8001',1 from dual
```

Second:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1_1', 'val1_2', 'val1_3')
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val2_1', 'val2_2', 'val2_3')
   INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val3_1', 'val3_2', 'val3_3')
   .
   .
   .
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Could anyone argue the preference of using one over another?

P.S. I didn't do any research myself (even explanation plan), so any information or opinion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

From performance's point of view, these queries are identical.

`UNION ALL` won't hurt performance, since `Oracle` estimates the `UNION`'ed query only when it needs it, it doesn't cache the results first.

`SELECT` syntax is more flexible in that sense that you can more easuly manupulate the `SELECT` query if you want to change something.

For instance, this query:

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
          select 8000,0,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
union all select 8001,0,'Multi 8001',1 from dual
```

can be rewritten as

```
INSERT
INTO    pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
SELECT  7999 + level, 0, 'Multi ' || 7999 + level, 1
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level <= 2
```

By replacing `2` with appropriate number, you can get any number of rows you want.

In case of `INSERT ALL`, you would have to duplicate the destination table description, which is less readable if you need, say, `40` rows.

Comment: Note that using `SOME_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` as value, gives an Oracle error **ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here** (Oracle 11g). A workaround is described here: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/54217/2/ - try `INSERT INTO ... SELECT SOME_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, T.* FROM (SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...) T`

Answer (score 4):

The `INSERT ALL` method has a problem with inserting bigger number of rows into a table.

I recently wanted to insert 1130 rows into a table with single SQL statement. When I tried to do this with `INSERT ALL` method I got the following error:

> ORA-24335 - cannot support more than 1000 columns

When I used `INSERT INTO .. UNION ALL ..` approach everything went fine.

Btw. I didn't know about the UNION ALL method before I found this discussion :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect solution 1 is a bit of a hack that works and is probably less efficient than the designed alternative of Insert ALL.

Insert all is really designed for you to insert many rows into more than 1 table as a result of a select, eg:

```
Insert ALL
into 
  t1 (c1, c2) values (q1, q2)
  t2 (x1, x2) values (q1, q3)
select q1, q2, q3 from t3
```

If you want to load thousands of rows **and they are not in the database already**, I don't think this is the best way to do it - If your data is in a file, you want to look at External Tables or SQL Loader to efficiently insert the rows for you.

Answer (score 3):

i tried some test and the faster solution should be

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
          select 8000,0,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
union all select 8001,0,'Multi 8001',1 from dual
```

buffering between 300 <-> 400 rows (i tried with odbc, this value could depends about its configuration)

Answer (score 2):

The statement utilizing the `UNION ALL` has theoretically a small performance disadvantage as it has to union the results of all statements before the insert can happen.
The `INSERT ALL` doesn't have this disadvantage as the final result can already be processed line-by-line.

But practically the optimizer inside Oracle should make the difference negligible and it is up to your preferences which way you choose.

In my own opinion the `INSERT ALL` is the better human-readable of the two while the `UNION ALL` variant is the one taking less space when such an insert is automatically generated.

Comment: Agreed with the conclusion, but:

Nitpick: these INSERT statements do not return any values, so it is meaningless to say anything happens "before the insert can happen" or "line-by-line". Anyway, he's using UNION ALL so there is no problem with sorts, if that is what you were thinking of.

Comment: A quick "explain plan" shows that the INSERT ALL with 4 lines int SCOTT.EMP has a cost of 2 (1 multi-table insert with the only CPU-cost in the dual-select) while the UNION ALL variant has a cost of 8 (with every SELECT causing another 2). Its not sorting but the combining of the results and the single (at least FAST DUAL) selects which are causing the cost.

Answer (score -1):

If you have insert statements that are more than 1000 then put all the insert statements in a .sql file and open that in Toad or SQL Developer and then execute. All records will get inserted.

Comment: OP wanted to know if one of the approaches he mentioned is to be preferred over the other, it is not about how/where to execute the SQL.

Answer (score -3):

You should consider Array-Insert.

- Easy SQL
- need some client-side coding to setup the array-Parameters

This is the way to minimize the Network-Traffic if some hundred inserts needs to be done in a batch.