# MyBatis Insert List values

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

Mapper.xml (Mapper xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="TestDAO">
<insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.List">
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, name) VALUES
<foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" open="(" separator=","  close=")">
#{element.id}, #{element.name}
</foreach>
</insert>
</mapper>
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
  private List<Emp> list = new ArrayList<Emp>();
  public List<Emp> getList() {
    return list;
  }
  public void setList(List<Emp> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Emp.java

```
public class Emp {
  public Emp(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  private int id;
  private String name;
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

TestDAO.java

```
public interface TestDAO {
public Integer insertEmployeeList(List<Emp> empList) throws SQLException;
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
       TestDAO tm = session.getMapper(TestDAO.class);
       Employee e = new Employee();
       Emp e11 = new Emp(123,"abc");
       Emp e12 = new Emp(456,"def");
       e.getList().add(e11);
       e.getList().add(e12);
       tm.insertEmployeeList(e.getList());
   }
}
```

Exception I'm getting is:

```
Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00913: too many values
The error may involve com.XXXX.sample.test.dao.TestDAO.insertEmployeeList-Inline
The error occurred while setting parameters
Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00913: too many values
```

Comment: class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    TestDAO tm = session.getMapper(TestDAO.class);
    Employee e = new Employee();
    Emp e11 = new Emp(123,"abc");
    Emp e12 = new Emp(456,"def");
    e.getList().add(e11);
    e.getList().add(e12);
    tm.insertEmployeeList(e.getList());
    }
    }

Comment: could you edit your last comment into your question, please? It makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: also please add the TestDAO as well.

Comment: Is that fine? Kindly revert in case of any clarifications

Comment: `public Integer insertEmployeeList(@Param("list") List<Emp> empList) throws SQLException` I mean with the *@Param* may help to some

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.xxxx.sample.test.dao.TestDAO">
  <insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.List">
   INSERT ALL  
    <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" >
     INTO EMPLOYEE (id,name) values (#{element.id},#{element.name})
    </foreach>
   SELECT * FROM dual
 </insert>
</mapper>
```

This is how the query should be there in Mapper xml

Comment: and how we can get auto incremented ids of list elements?

Comment: The only problem I see with this approach is test-ability. How would you unit-test this mapper against an offline in-memory database ? (H2 , for example)

Comment: Why are we using `SELECT * FROM dual` ?

Comment: @ShlomiKirály For unit testing you have a few examples here: https://github.com/mybatis/jpetstore-6/tree/master/src/test/java/org/mybatis/jpetstore/service

Comment: @AnupKumarGupta if you did not have the `SELECT * FROM dual` you will get ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. I do not know why though

Answer (score 23):

As I use MySQL as a Data base, after a couple of tries this is how it worked for me.

```xml
<insert id="insert" parameterType="java.util.List">
    INSERT INTO games (
    id,
    game_id,
    game_vendor,
    game_code,
    game_name,
    game_type)
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" open="(" separator="),("  close=")">
        #{element.id},
        #{element.gameId},
        #{element.gameVendor},
        #{element.gameCode},
        #{element.gameName},
        #{element.gameType},
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use annotations (**@org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert**) for executing a single insert for your entire list.

**Remember:** *You wont need any sql provider class.*

```
public interface SomethingMapper {

    @Insert({
        "<script>",
        "INSERT INTO your_database_name.your_table_name",
            "(column1_int, column2_str, column3_date, column4_time)",
        "VALUES" +  
            "<foreach item='each_item_name' collection='theCollection' open='' separator=',' close=''>" +
                "(" +
                    "#{each_item_name.column1,jdbcType=INTEGER},",
                    "#{each_item_name.column2,jdbcType=VARCHAR},",
                    "(SELECT SOME_DB_FUNCTION(#{each_item_name.column3,jdbcType=DATE})),",
                    "#{each_item_name.period.start,jdbcType=TIME}" +
                ")" +
            "</foreach>",
    "</script>"})
    void insertBatchSomething(@Param("theCollection") List<Something> theCollection);

}
```

**Output SQL if you have 2 items:**

```
SQL: INSERT INTO your_database_name.your_table_name (column1_int, column2_str, column3_date, column4_time) VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT SOME_DB_FUNCTION(?)), ?), (?, ?, (SELECT SOME_DB_FUNCTION(?)), ?)
```

**P.S.**

**@Insert** receives a String[], so for each value it will add a whitespace between Strings.

Comment: Hi, using `collection='theCollection'` (meaning the name of the `List`) didn't work. Only `collection='list'` can be used in any case. Anyway, this is the way to use `annotation` in inserting **many rows**

Comment: I'm using **MyBatis 3.4.4**, and yes, you can custom your collection name. I'm using a custom name here and works fine. Just **remember to use @Param("theCollection")** or else it wont really work.

Comment: Hi, you are right, the `@Param("theCollection")` is the key

Comment: I think we should add `index` attribute to the `<foreach>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your logging system to print out the generated Queries, then try to execute them to your DB directly.

In your case, the expected query SHOULD be

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, name) VALUES
(123, "abc")(456, "def")
```

as far as I can remember that is not valid. `INSERT INTO` only takes one set of `VALUES`. I looked up the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm) and it looks like this there as well.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883706/inserting-multiple-rows-into-oracle) on how to `INSERT` multiple rows in oracle.

Comment: Logging the query helped me to fix the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[tistory]http://woniperstory.tistory.com/194  : This link shows the right answer !!!

```
public  someClass {

    public void someMethod() {

        Map<String,Object> map =  new HashMap<String,Object>() ;
        List<Emp> list =  new ArrayList<Emp>() ;

        ::::  add Emp Objects to list

        map.put("list", list)

        public Integer insertEmployeeList(map) ;
    }
}

public interface TestDAO {
    public Integer insertEmployeeList(Map<String,Object> map) throws SQLException;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"  
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">  
<mapper namespace="TestDAO">  
<insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.Map">  
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (id, name) VALUES  
<foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" separator=",">  
    ( #{element.id}, #{element.name} )  
</foreach>  
</insert>  
</mapper>
```