# How to insert Arraylist in MyBatis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

Hello today I have problem with insert Arraylist using Mybatis like code bellow:

```
@Insert("<script>"
            + "   <foreach collection='USER_LIST' item='User' separator=';'> "
            + "      insert into tbl_user(username,role) values(#{User.username},#{User.role})"
            + "  </foreach>"
            + "</script>")
```

When I insert single item of arraylist , it worked. but If i have multiple item in arraylist error occured:

```
 insert into tbl_user(username,role)             values(?,?);   ;        values(?,?);
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';        values('BEAN','BMd')' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';        values('BEAN','BMd')' at line 1; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563463/mybatis-insert-list-values) may help you.

Comment: ok , It worked now thank  you

Comment: **Take a look at this link:** [MyBatis Insert List values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563463/mybatis-insert-list-values/45693515#45693515)

Answer (score 0):

from the exception, "bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is ",
and i find this in your code "separator=';'>", that's right, myBatis not allowed you to write ';'