# How do you insert a list of elements in database instead of one by one in the list

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

This is a example of my query for insert,

```
<insert Id = insertRecord>
insert into RECORD (RECORD_ID, RECORD_NAME) VALUES(RECORD_SEQ.NEXTVAL, #RECORDNAME:VARCHAR#)
</insert>
```

Right now what I do is I have a list of record name let's say recordsList = [a,b,c,d,e], I call the query inside of loop.

```
 for (record rec in recordsList){ //record had it variable type record
        insertRecord(rec); // that will call the insert query at top
 }
```

Can anyone give me hint that how to insert the whole list once, instead of call 
 the query every single time in the loop.

https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html

I found that in iBatis there is something call iterate may help, but I can't understand the example they given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis Insert List values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563463/mybatis-insert-list-values)

Comment: Looks great, I am testing right now, thank you so much. :)