# Inserting lists into a separate table MYBATIS

Tags: spring, mybatis

I need help inserting the following data to db
i have two tables employee and employee_skills
(1 employee can have many skills)

mapper.xml

```
<insert id='addEmp1' parameterType='Employee'
    useGeneratedKeys='true '>
    INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."EMPLOYEE"("ADDRESS", "AGE", "CITY", "DEPT",
    "FNAME","LNAME", "SALARY", "STATE")
    values(#{address},#{age},#{city},#{dept},#{fname},#{lname},#{salary},#{state});

</insert>
```

I have two separate tables here

```
<insert id='addskills' parameterType='Employee'
    useGeneratedKeys='true '>
    INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."EMPLOYEE_SKILLS"
    ( "EMPLOYEE_E_ID", "SKILLS" )
    VALUES (
    <foreach collection="skills" item="skill" separator=",">
        #{id},#{employee.skills}</foreach>)
     </insert>
```

DAO

```
    SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
      try{
      EmployeeDAO userMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(EmployeeDAO.class);                                        //sqlSession.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
      // userMapper.addEmp(employee);                                                                       //userMapper.insertUser(employee);
    sqlSession.insert("addEmp1",employee);
    sqlSession.insert("addskill",employee);

      sqlSession.commit();
      }finally{
       sqlSession.close();
      }
```

This doesnt seem to work i'm new to mybatis please help

Comment: The generated sql is incorrect. See [MyBatis Insert List values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563463/mybatis-insert-list-values) for answers about insertion of the list.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `SqlSession`, you must combine the namespace and query id specified in xml.
See [Official Documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#Exploring_Mapped_SQL_Statements).