# Php: how to use less queries

Tags: php, mysql

There is fan based php game, and one of its file's has over 300 queries. I thought of optimizing it and making it with less queries so it doent crash, and so it runs faster.

So my question is how do i make a php script with less queries.

Example:

```
if ('this' == 'this')
{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(' ', '$user', 'pass'"); 
}


if ('1' == '1')
{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(' ', '$user', 'pass'"); 
}
```

I thought of trying this:

```
function do()
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(' ', '$user', 'pass'");     
}


if ('crap' == 'crap')
{
    do();    
}


if ('1' == '1')
{     
    do();    
}
```

But then realized it the same, so any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Why do you have so many queries in the first place ? It's hard to help you without knowing *what* you're doing.

Comment: mysql is deprecated. please use PDO or mysqli

Comment: use multi row inserts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Comment: Is it always the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example all you need to do is have the `variables` change on the `if statements` and run one query.

```
function do(insert your parameters)
{

  if (blah == blah)
  {


      if ('1' == '1')
      {     
        // set variables 
      }

      elseif('crap' == 'crap') 
      {
        //set variables
      }

      else 
      {
      // set variables
      }

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(' ', '$user', 'pass'");     

  }

  else {

  return false;

  }

}
```

This may also be a great canidate for the `switch case statement`. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch ($myvariable) {
    case "crap":
        $myvariable = "blah";
        break;
    case 1:
        $myvariable = "blah";
        break;
    default:
       $myvariable = "blah";
}
```

That is a quick example but not knowing exactly what you need this may help. I also suggest you use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` as `mysql` has been deprecated.

Comment: I know good php :), i was just asking for a way to use less queries so the server running the script would not crash.

Comment: Oh ok :) We'll maybe I gave you a few good ideas. As I mentioned I really don't know your script and how things are calling the DB but maybe joining tables will help cut down some of the queries as well.