# SQL Syntax error, when executing several queries?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using a readymade script to backup my MySQL database using PHP. I store the resultant query in a variable.

If I echo the variable, and copy paste the output into the MySQL console, it works perfectly.

But when I run the same using 'mysql_query' (I know it is depreciated, kindly ignore that), I get the dreaded Syntax error.

Here's the echo output (first 2 lines) :

> INSERT INTO `assign`
>   VALUES('75085','rsam','CE0001/CZ0001/CPE183/CSC183','1','1','3.0','13','1','1','13','2','10.00','117.00','0','0');INSERT
>   INTO `assign`
>   VALUES('75086','rsam','CE0001/CZ0001/CPE183/CSC183','1','2','3.0','13','1','1','13','2','10.00','97.50','0','0');

And here's the exact error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `assign`
>   VALUES('75085','rsam','CE0001/CZ0001/CPE183/CSC183','1','1'' at line 1

If anyone can point out what I am obviously missing, I would be grateful!

Comment: Have you tried enumerating your field list?

Comment: `mysql_query()` does not allow multiple queries. [`mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) ...`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative?

Comment: do 2 `mysql_query()` calls or update to mysqli and use `mysqli_multi_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: yes you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330243/sql-syntax-error-when-there-is-none/19330268#19330268

Comment: @ShaktiPatel why are comment linking to your own answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation for [`mysql_query()`](http://docs.php.net/mysql_query) says:

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified `link_identifier`.

You might be interested in [`mysql_multi_query()`](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.multi-query):

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

While `mysql_query` is limited to a single statement, this situation can be avoided as multiple records can be inserted into the same table with only one statement:

```
INSERT INTO assign (...)
VALUES(...),
VALUES(...);
```

This will save on round-trip latency (over multiple `mysql_query`) which might matter.

See [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6889065/2864740)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, but unfortunately the list also has 'CREATE TABLE' queries, which I didn't include here for simplicity.