# creating a database to insert into from data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am learning php/sql/wamp and have encountered much trouble on a learning project...

i have a txt file below ive finally figured out away to load it into php however i cant figure out how to approach creating the database sql needed to insert this data into and perform queries...  is there a good link or tutorial or perhaps sample code?  below is my php and txt code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n<datalist>";
$content = $header."\n".file_get_contents("data.txt")."\n</datalist>";
$ob = simplexml_load_string($content);
$json = json_encode($ob);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$alldata = $array["pub"];

foreach ($alldata as $key => $value) { //access all data in loop
$id = $value["ID"];
$title = $value["title"];
$year = $value["year"];
$booktitle = $value["booktitle"];
$pages = $value["pages"];
$authors = implode(",", $value["authors"]["author"]);
//All process data can available here .run your sql query for insert.
}

?>
```

and my txt file below.. same format but for 50mb of data

```
<pub>
<ID>0</ID>
<title>Regression Time Warping for Similarity Measure of Sequence</title>
<year>2004</year>
<booktitle>CIT</booktitle>
<pages>826-830</pages>
<authors>
        <author>Hansheng Lei</author>
        <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
</authors>
</pub>
<pub>
<ID>1</ID>
<title>A Computational Model for Face Location Based on Cognitive Principles</title>
<year>1992</year>
<booktitle>AAAI</booktitle>
<pages>350-355</pages>
<authors>
        <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
        <author>Sargur N. Srihari</author>
        <author>David B. Sher</author>
</authors>
</pub>
```

Comment: $ob = simplexml_load_string($content);
$json = json_encode($ob);
$array = json_decode($json, true);

why are you loading it into an object, then json encoding it, then decoding it into an array? Am I missing the reason why you don't just use the object from the beginning?

Comment: are you sugguesting $array=$ob?

Comment: There are probably thousands of tutorials around MySQL and how to interact with it in PHP both here on SO and to the intreped Googler.

Comment: I'm suggesting $ob = simplexml_load_string($content); is all that you need. You are creating an object, then converting it to another object, and then converting it to an array. You can access the properties you want via the $ob object.

Comment: Read about PDO or mysqli though in regards to your mysql-related question. I'll help clear up your unnecessary code though if you don't understand what I'm saying.

Comment: should i not be using wamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your table in MySQL.  Then use mysqli (or PDO) to insert the data.

```
/**
 *  Connect to database
 */
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/**
 *  Loop data
 */
foreach ($alldata as $key => $value) { //access all data in loop
    /**
     *  Insert row.  This assumes that your table columns are in the 
     *  same order as the variables as they are given below
     */
    $authors = implode(",", $value["authors"]["author"]);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', 
                       $value["ID"], 
                       $value["title"], 
                       $value["year"], 
                       $value["booktitle"], 
                       $value["pages"], implode(",", $value["authors"]["author"]));
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Note that it is possible to insert multiple records using MySQL.  ([Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql.))  You could do this to cut down on the number of inserts, but it makes building the query more complicated.

Also note that using a single table for this data isn't optimal.  Ideally you would use three tables:

- Books = all books
- Authors = all authors
- Author_book = the relationship between a book and its many authors

Think about the following problems with using a single table:

- What happens when one of your <author> entries contains a comma?  Your code uses commas to implode the list of authors, thus...
  <authors>
  <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
  <author>Sargur N. Srihari</author>
  <author>David B. Sher, PhD</author>
  </authors>
  ...becomes Venu Govindaraju, Sargur N. Srihari, David B. Sher, PhD.
- How would you find all books authored by Author A and Author B?  You would have to create some overly complex method for keyword searching the author column in the DB.

Comment: very indepth thank you i am attempting to work it... should i not be using wamp?

Comment: how did you do this without mentioning data.txt file? i dont understand how it could load if it doesnt know what file to load?

Answer (score -1):

Before your for loop you need to connect to the database and then inside your for loop you need to insert each row that you read from the data file. What does your table structure look like? Have you tried to write any of the SQL yourself?

Connecting to a database: http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-using-php/

Inserting into a database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Downvoted for outdated article. Please suggest something that isn't deprecated (mysql_*) :p

Comment: should i not be using wamp?