# insert single set of data multiple times mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert single set of data multiple times , say n rows.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("John", 123, "US");
```

Can I insert all n rows in a single SQL statement?

here `n` is dynamic value n is user input , how to make insert query n times , any idea.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES(`field1`,`field2`,`field3`) VALUES ";
$count = 5;
for($i=0;$i<$coutn;$i++)
{
$sql .= " ('john','123','us' )";
}
```

is this correct way..

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql . In your case, therefore, it should be something like `INSERT INTO MyTable (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ("John",123,"US"),("John2",123,"US2") [...]`

Comment: You want to insert *the same data* multiple times?  Why?  Why not simply include an additional column `number_of_times`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this can be done easily, it should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ("John", 123, "US"), ("Carl", 123, "EU"), ("Jim", 123, "FR");
```

However, it is good programming practice to specify the *columns* of your table in the query, for example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
VALUES ("John", 123, "US"), ("Carl", 123, "EU"), ("Jim", 123, "FR");
```

EDIT : You can build your query like this (in `for` cycle), the `$total` is your user input:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES";

//Build SQL INSERT query
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
  $sql .= " ($value1, $value2, $value3), ";
}
//Trim the last comma (,)
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
//Now, the $sql var contains the complex query. 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

As you can see **we do not** execute the `INSERT` statement in the loop, but rather we build the SQL query text and *then* we will execute it in one pass.

Comment: i dont know how many "n" times im gng to insert ,  n is user input

Comment: @SteveBals $n = $total, and note that the mysql_ api is deprecated