# how to create 1k rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a small question on how to create 1k rows as in sample below format in mysql using php

```
 for ($i = 0;$i < 1000;$i++) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `tt_test` (`id`, `name` ,`year`,`payment`,`address`) VALUES (null,"asdasdsad'.$i.'",rand(2010,2015),rand('pending','success','failed','refunded'),"abcd'.$i.'")';
    $preparesql = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $executesql = $preparesql->execute(array());
}
```

can any one help me out.... thank you -kanth

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code is not very performant, but the idea is correct - loop and add a row.

Comment: I think you forgot to escape the quote.

Comment: `$executesql = $preparesql->execute(array());` What's this? Also, your example is PHP and mysql, not only SQL. You're quite confused, aren't you?

Comment: You can also just concatenate all queries into one string (INSERT can add mutiple value sets with one call) and safe much on performance.

Comment: Anyways, next time please tell us what your actual problem is. Your question is VERY unclear.

Comment: And you have mixed usage of single and double quotes for values in your resulting sql string. I think MySQL uses single quotes for it's values.

Comment: @ToBe You're right. If perfomance is a problem, kanth has to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql/6889087#6889087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using prepared statements. You're preparing the query 1000 times, but you only have to prepare it once.

Here's an example using a PDO:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tt_test` (`name` ,`year`,`payment`,`address`) VALUES (:name,:year,:payment,:address)";
$preparesql = $DBH->prepare($sql);

for ($i = 0;$i < 1000;$i++) {
    $params = array();
    $params[':name'] = 'asdasdsad'.$i;
    $params[':year'] = rand(2010,2015);
    $params[':payment'] = rand('pending','success','failed','refunded');
    $params[':address'] = 'abcd'.$i;
    $executesql = $preparesql->execute($params);
}
```

It's easier to prepare a query (once!) and then add the parameters to it. Your code is easier to read (and maintain) and you'll prevent SQL injections as well.

Comment: Not to mention it's faster. injection in this case is not the biggest worry though because no outside variables are used.

Answer (score 0):

Definately look at the link provided by @Mithredate because MySQL gets unwieldy at a certain point but this should make your code work:

```
 for ($i = 0;$i < 1000;$i++) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `tt_test` (`id`, `name` ,`year`,`payment`,`address`) VALUES (null,"asdasdsad'.$i.'",rand(2010,2015),rand("pending","success","failed","refunded"),"abcd'.$i.'")';
    $preparesql = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $executesql = $preparesql->execute(array()); }
```

**EDIT:** I stuck to what you provided to show you how close you were to getting it work, Stephan Vierkant's solution is a nicer solution once you get what you did wrong in your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how, without PHP:

```
create table num(n int not null primary key) engine=InnoDB;

insert num(n) 
values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);


INSERT INTO `tt_test` (`id`, `name`, `year`, `payment`, `address`) 
select
    null, 
    concat('asdasdsad', n1.n + n2.n * 10 + n3.n * 100), 
    floor(2010 + 5 * rand()), 
    elt(floor(1 + 4 * rand()), 'pending', 'success', 'failed', 'refunded'),
    concat('abcd', n1.n + n2.n * 10 + n3.n * 100)
from num n1
join num n2 on 1=1
join num n3 on 1=1;
```

Pros: you have a "service table" which you can use to generate sequences.

Cons: no PHP :)

Answer (score -1):

Because of the size of your queries, You might ran into execution time problems.
[This](http://www.seancolombo.com/2009/07/05/quick-tip-do-huge-mysql-queries-in-batches-when-using-php/) might help you.

Comment: Sorry, your link has got nothing to do with the question

Comment: I thought your problem was the max_execution_time in php configuration, so I suggested a way to do your query a bit faster, which is BATCH.