# looping mysql query to get multiple rows of data from a table and insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a small project and is having some issues with looping MySQL insert. I currently have 2 database tables. I am fetching information from one to another.

table with data:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM HARDWARE WHERE ID_2=".$db->qstr(20);
$rss = $db->execute($q);
$re2=$rss->GetArray();
```

so I am getting the array of data fine.

inserting the data only if the id is {20}
Currently I have 2 rows with ID_2 = 20 but it is only inserting one row not both. here is my insert query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS SET
          IN_ID     =". $db->qstr($in_id).",
      ER_ID     =". $db->qstr( $er_id).",
      ITEM      =". $db->qstr( $re2[0]['ITEM']   ).",
      NAME      =". $db->qstr( $re2[0]['NAME']   );
```

it inserts the data fine, just one row not multiple rows. any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not do the insert in MySQL?

Comment: Add your insert query in loop of your returning result.

Comment: yea I need to insert in loop. from what I know my query should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert your query in a loop

`foreach ($re2 as $r):
    $sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS SET
          IN_ID     =". $db->qstr($in_id).",
      ER_ID     =". $db->qstr( $er_id).",
      ITEM      =". $db->qstr( $r['ITEM']   ).",
      NAME      =". $db->qstr( $r['NAME']   );
    endforeach;`

or use multiple inserts
[Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

both should be fine at what you have there.

Comment: can I not just use foreach in this case?

Comment: `var_dump` your array to see what's in there. I'll update my post with a foreach loop.

Comment: I tried this too but it is inserting incorrect data. I am getting 4 and 5 as values

Comment: ok I made a mistake. this is working well. thank you Marius C

Comment: foreach ($re2 as $r){  $sql = "INSERT INTO PARTS SET
          IN_ID     =". $db->qstr($in_id).",
      ER_ID     =". $db->qstr( $er_id).",
      ITEM      =". $db->qstr( $r['ITEM']   ).",
      NAME      =". $db->qstr( $r['NAME']   );
}