# Insert more than one records in mysql Table

Tags: mysql

I am inserting records to MySQL Table using the following Query :

```
insert into table(field1, field2) values(1,2);
```

Now again when I want to add data I am using the above query only change data like :

```
insert into table(field1, field2) values(3,4);
```

So is there a way using which I can add more data at a time ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Although this question is duplicate, I feel that this question is better worded and the other question should instead be flagged as duplicate and point to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query :

```
INSERT INTO table(field1, field2) VALUES(1,2),(4,5),(7,8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just list all the tuples you want to insert in one query, like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) values (1, 2), (3, 4);
```

Or you can specify the inserted data by a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2)
SELECT field3, field4 FROM table2
WHERE conditions;
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert more than one record at once, we can do this, with each set of field values separated by a comma:

```
 INSERT INTO table
 VALUES
 (field1, field2),
 (field1, field2),
 (field1, field2),
 (field1, field2)...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(field1, field2) VALUES(1,2),
                                        (3,4),
                                        ..... ;
```