# ASP.Net Insert multiple labels into different Database rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, bulkinsert

I have **dynamically created labels** which has id as "`label+i`". Those labels get their text from again **dynamically created textboxes** with id's as "`"text"+i`". I get total numbers of textbox from user. What I'm trying is if I get 12 labels I want to have 3 row in total. All rows has 4 columns in db. Max number of label will be 28 or 32 so there will not be a hundred of labels.

For example if I have

```
 label1, label2, label3, label4,label5,label6,label7,label8
```

**then first row of database will be**

```
    col1=label1
    col2=label2
    col3=label3
    col4=label4
```

**and second row will be**

```
    col1=label5
    col2=label6
    col3=label7
    col4=label8
```

Since I don't know how to *separate rows in a single query execution* I couldn't think of a good algorithm. I need your help guys :)

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are only talking about a few rows, why do you care if you have to do it over 7 or 8 queries, I doubt there would be a performance gain by using some kind of bulk insert technique for 7 or 8 rows.

Comment: See this question for inserting multiple rows in one query, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can do itsimple but hopefully will give you an idea how to do it.

```
for (int i=1;i<=NumOfLabels;i++){

if (i%4==0)
{
insert  into yourTable values( labels[i-4],labels[i-3],labels[i-2],labels[i-1]);
}

}
```