# Trigger error with mysql in the second case

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i am new to mysql.I have did some code with mysql trigger but it throws me error on the second condition.
The code

## This one works fine

```
create table foo (a INT, b INT, ts TIMESTAMP);
create table bar (a INT, b INT);

INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(4,2);


INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(3,3);


CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo

FOR EACH ROW
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);



UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;
```

It succesfully outputs `5`.

## The error code

```
create table foo (a INT, b INT, ts TIMESTAMP);
create table bar (a INT, b INT);

INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(5,1);
INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(4,2);
INSERT INTO foo (a,b) VALUES(3,3);



CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);

UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;
```

When i called like `select a from bar where b = 1`.The expected result is `5 and 4`.

But instead of it .it outputs like  `Schema Creation Failed: Unknown column 'OLD.a' in 'field list':`

So my question is why doesnt the second option work here ..Whay cant i add `NEW.a and NEW.b` in the insert statement second time.

Thanx for the help..

Comment: Did you really mean to insert the same values twice in the second version? Why do you expect the results of the `SELECT` to be `5` and `4`? I just get `5`.

Comment: @Barmar see when we use `UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;` the value of a and b would be 3 and 1 which is a new value..I have used `insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);` so in the old section it must be 5 which works fine ..and there in the second row the old value is 4 ..why 4 isnt printed instead of outputting 5 .what i want in the output is 5 and 4.

Comment: @Barmar the old value is set to 5(which is from the first row in the second row thew old value of a is 4 ..why cant it be accessed ??.is it possible with triggers ??.if yes please help me ..

Comment: The second row is irrelevant, because it doesn't match `WHERE b = 1`, so the `UPDATE` doesn't affect it.

Comment: @Barmar so the update statement only causes the changes to the first row value ..not on the second ??..is there any way to make chages to the second row value with triggers ??

Comment: That's the whole point of the `WHERE` clause. Take out `WHERE b = 1` and it will update all rows. Or use `WHERE b IN (1, 2)` to update just the first two rows.

Comment: @Barmar yeah i have did like `UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;` so the  b value of the both row are 1..and when i use  like `select a from bar where b = 1` it only shows 5 ..it didnt output 4..so my question is is there any way in mysql trigger to make changes to the second row value.

Comment: When you use `FOR EACH ROW` it only operates on the rows that are affected by the `UPDATE` statement, not every row in the table.

Comment: You're making changes to a different table. Why do you think this trigger should be run on those rows?

Comment: @Barmar so what i asked is ..is there any way to make changes to the whole row instead of the dirst row with mysql trigger ??..

Comment: @Barmar i just want to know that if its possible to make changes to the second row with the update condition with trigger

Comment: You can put `UPDATE foo SET b = OLD.b WHERE b = 2` into the trigger.

Comment: @Barmar throws Schema Creation Failed: Unknown column 'OLD.b' in 'field list':

Comment: @Barmar actually is it possible to acheieve this with triggers ..or is it only possible to make changes to the first row ??..i have tried many methods but still it isnt working at all.

Comment: I get a different error: `Can't update table 'foo' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`. So you can't do this with a trigger, you're not allowed to modify the table that you're triggering on.

Comment: You can make changes to any row with `UPDATE`. But the trigger can only make changes to a different table.

Comment: @Barmar what i want to do is to make changes to the row..and i have used update statement as you mentioned but it didnt worked at all ..sir do you know why ?

Comment: You can only use `OLD.` in a trigger. You got your error because you tried to use `OLD.b` in a normal UPDATE statement.

Comment: I think you need to start a new question. It sounds like what you want to do has nothing to do with triggers, you're just confused about how to write UPDATE statements.

Comment: it throws error Schema Creation Failed: Can't update table 'foo' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.:

Comment: @Barmar see when i use old.a it corresponds to 5 which is the value of the first row of a ...what i want to do is to access the value of second row that is 4..why didnt i get the outut 4 when i used old.a where b = 1..is it possible with triggers..this is my question.or with triggers can we only make changes to first row with old and new .

Comment: `OLD` means the old value of the row that is being changed by the `UPDATE` statement. It doesn't access any other rows.

Comment: If your second row started with `b = 1` then it would also be seen in the trigger. But it has `b = 2`, so it isn't updated.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something very fundamental, and I can't figure out what's confusing you. It's really very simple. Unfortunately, I have to leave for the day, I won't be able to continue until tonight.

Comment: @Barmar i have called the update statement anyway ..so you say its only possible to make changes to the row with update statement ??..i have called update statement but it never worked.

Comment: @Barmar yay i got the working now ...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `DELIMITER` command so that the semicolon doesn't end the trigger definition. You also need a `BEGIN ... END` block to put multiple commands into the `FOR EACH ROW` loop

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
        insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71e29/1)

Comment: this didnt helped me out ..I throws me error it would be really helpful if you show an sql fiddle..i would surely accept it

Comment: I've added a link to my sqlfiddle. It uses sqlfiddle's menu to set the statement delimiter; `DELIMITER` isn't a SQL statement, it's a UI feature of the `mysql` command line interface.

Comment: see when we use `UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;` the value of a and b would be 3 and 1 which is a new value..I have used ` insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);` so in the old section it must be 5 which works fine ..and there in the second row the old value is 4 ..why 4 isnt printed instead of outputting 5 .what i want in the output is 5 and 4.

Comment: In the second row the value of `b` is `2`, so `WHERE b = 1` doesn't match it and the trigger doesn't operate on that line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this section:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
```

is *two* statements.  You've got two semicolons, so MySQL is parsing it as two commands.  The first command being:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
```

The second one being:

```
insert into bar values(OLD.a,NEW.b);
```

That second command isn't valid.

---

Because you're inserting [multiple times into the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql), you can try something like this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
insert into bar values (OLD.a, NEW.b), (OLD.a, NEW.b);
```

Comment: can you provide me an sql fiddle answer ..it would be helpful for me to figure

Comment: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values(OLD.a,NEW.b)' at line 4:

Comment: What the heck were you running?  It works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f51186/1