# SQL to INSERT-DELETE disjoint rows into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a `food_table` and a `person_table`. Then I have a third table `fav_food_table` that stores the relation between food and person using `food_id` and `person_id`.

When the person goes to account info and updates his favourite food, the input data is passed to the PHP (HTTP) script as an array of selected `food_id`. A person can have multiple fav_food, the relation is one-to-many.

The naïve way to update `fav_food_table` is to delete from `fav_food_table` all that belongs to `person_id` then re-insert all the rows again. Thus, using 2 statements.

Is there a single statement that can do the same thing?

PSUEDO CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE food_table (food_id, food_name);
CREATE TABLE person_table (person_id, person_name);
CREATE TABLE fav_food (person_id, food_id);
```

Comment: Can you post table structure for those tables in question.

Comment: It's just a simple structure... I have edited.

Comment: Is there any relationship b/w food and person table?

Comment: Not directly. The relationship is fav_food.

Comment: Ok, what you are trying to update in fav_food table?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I am trying to record new set of favourite food in fav_food. If that is what you want?

Comment: There is something called a combined where clause. You can specificly narrow things down with using multiple where clause, by using the `and`. Check my answer since I use it there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a m:n relationship between `person_table` and `food_table`. This means you have multiple records in your relationship table related to the same person. When a person updates their favourite foods, any combination of four independent cases can occur:

1. Food A was favourite before, but is not anymore (`DELETE FROM fav_food_table`)
2. Food B was favourite before and still is! (*do nothing*)
3. Food C was no favourite before, but now is a favourite (`INSERT INTO fav_food_table`)
4. Food D was no favourite before, and still is no favourite! (*do nothing*)

To correctly keep your database up to date, you have to handle all four cases. Cases 2 and 4 are covered easily. Just don't do anything :)

That means, you have to do at least two steps to keep your database up to date: 1 and 3.

**Your goal seems to be to reduce the number of sql statements, that have to be executed.**

Deleting all favourites for one person from the table can always be done with a single statement:

```
DELETE
FROM fav_food_table
WHERE person_id = ?;
```

To delete selected favourites for one person, only an `AND food_id IN (?,?,?)` has to be added to the `WHERE` clause.

Inserting into the table can also be done with a [single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql):

```
INSERT INTO fav_food_table (person_id,food_id)
VALUES (?,?),
       (?,?),
       (?,?),
       .....;
```

**Summary as of right now:**
No matter, whether we delete all old records for this person and then insert all new records, or whether we only delete selected records and insert new ones: We can do it with two statements!

In the second case (the "smart" case), however, we need to know not only the new state of the relation, but also the old state to compute the difference between the two. This will result in either one more `SELECT` statement or needs some smart "client" (PHP) logic.

**Your two step process doesn't seem to be naive, but easy and effective to me. There is no way to reduce this process to less than two statements.**

*If you want to reduce the number of times you have to effectively send commands from PHP to the server, you can either look into [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) or into creating a stored procedure which holds both your `DELETE` and `INSERT` statement. But bottom line, this will be the same thing as executing the two queries on its own.
You can also look into [MySQL Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples) to implement a safer process and be able to rollback your `DELETE` command should an error occur later on.*

Comment: Another problem of delete is that it will cause the keys to change (esp. for more complex fav_food table with primary key for example) and trigger reindex etc. which are unnecessary. I thought it will be good if that can be avoided. I believe this is a common design after all and would like to see if there were more ingenious methods.

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest something different. Instead of deleting, updating?

Deleting data in common is something that should be thought off. Deleting data cannot be retrieved. So check this out.

We are adjusting your code a bit.

```
CREATE TABLE food_table (food_id, food_name);
CREATE TABLE person_table (person_id, person_name);
CREATE TABLE fav_food (person_id, food_id, fav_food_active); 
/* see the last column i added. It should be a bit type and can only hold the values 0 and 1. */
```

Now you technically can update this everytime. No need for deleting the values. This statement is

```
/* deletion */
UPDATE Fav_Food
SET fav_food_active = 0
WHERE food_id = (your food_id)
AND person_id = (your person_id)

/* activating it again */
UPDATE Fav_Food
SET fav_food_active = 1
WHERE food_id = (your food_id)
AND person_id = (your person_id)
```

So now you switch between those 2 for activating and deleting it, without having the consequences of deleting hard data. Overal, you can just call it like this in your code

```
SELECT *
FROM fav_food
WHERE (here your where clause on which you wanna search for)
AND fav_food_active = 1
```

Remember when you enter something in the database, you should always add it as 1. You can do that in PHP myadmin as auto value, or hard code it in your `INSERT` statement.

I am not sure what your backend code is (okay taking that back, its PHP, i read your post) looking at your question you shooting everything through an array, but try to work in some checks that `foreach` fav_food entry, check first in the db if the query excists. If it does, update it, if not, insert it. and let that run in a loop.

So something like

```
foreach ($food_id as $value){
    // check here the overal statement if it excists in your db
    // give back count
    if ($count == 1){
        // update query to delete it.
    }else{
        // create  your insert query here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Since you (basically) have to keep all possible person / food combinations in `fav_food` now, setting `fav_food_active=0` is not different to deleting the rows completely in a regular relationship table. "without having the consequences of deleting hard data." just does not apply here. The additional column has **no advantage**. Even worse, you are kind of working against the foreign key constraints, which should be set on the table, when done properly.

Comment: Well, he asked if there was another way, and I showed him the way I would interpreted it. I dont say its right way in the least, but the way I see it is that I not fight against the foreign key system here. The constrains are still used, I just add an extra field to hide / show it in the code within the view when called. I honestly dont like it if i use  `delete code` in my work, but thats my POV. His own way is the most effective one, I agree on that part.

Comment: Well, OP actually didn't ask for *another way*, but whether he would be able to update his relation table with **a single statement** instead of two. Your approach actually needs more then two statements, to update your table, because you need to use `UPDATE` :)

Comment: Yes, I guess I didnt read the question in that way. Thanks for the information @wolfgangwalther. And you showed me as well that I might handle my information wrong as well :). I guess I need to take a new look at this, and see if there is a solution to the problem. Cheers man!

Comment: Regarding FK constraints: I am trying to make a point regarding foreign keys, but I can't. You are probably right on that one ;)

Comment: But the main concern, that I have with your approach is, that the "soft deletion" you are introducing here doesn't work in that context, because there are not other columns in that table besides foreign keys. The relation is defined through the mere "existence" of those records in the table. Imagine I would set your additional `fav_food_active` column completely to 0 - would you be able to restore any of the relation information? No! And that's why there is no difference between your approach and the "hard delete".

Comment: Jep, you are completely right! There is no way to restore the old relation indeed.