# Insert Multipule rows single insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-records

First query I'm getting user_id records like below :

```
1
14
22
38
39
54
68
74
```

Now i want to insert above user_id's in another table in single query, like below :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Channel_Subscriber(user_id,channel_id,status,EntDate) VALUES(@user_id,@channel_id,@status,@EntDate).
```

How can i insert new record with single insert query

Comment: use a loop after reading values to insert

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting multiple rows in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 2 queries. Do it in one and add the variables to the first query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Channel_Subscriber(user_id,channel_id,status,EntDate) 
select user_id, @channel_id, @status, @EntDate
from first_table
```

Comment: #juergen d
 (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM tbl_Following_Followers  
 WHERE user_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT(followers_ID) FROM tbl_Following_Followers WHERE user_id=14 and status='Follow')
 OR user_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM tbl_Following_Followers WHERE followers_ID=14 and status='Follow')) .This Query i'm getting user_id's , how can i insert this query

Comment: INSERT INTO tbl_Channel_Subscriber(user_id,channel_id,status,EntDate)SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), @channel_id,@status,@EntDate FROM tbl_Following_Followers WHERE
 user_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT(followers_ID)  FROM tbl_Following_Followers  WHERE user_id=14 and status='Follow') OR user_id IN(SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM tbl_Following_Followers WHERE followers_ID=14 and status='Follow'))

Comment: #Arun your given query inserting records successfully  but some records not inserted i means if distinct user_id's effected 1,3,21,32,39 but only insert two or three records only insert