# complicated mongoose pull list of data from api and insert into mongodb if it doesn't already exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am connecting to the Yelp API using the RapidAPI module in Nodejs. I am able to request a token, connect, and request data, retrieve that data, and insert the relevant information for each result it into mongodb. Here's where it gets complicated...

Let's say I make a Yelp API request and search for bars. I get a list of bars and insert them into the database. Let's say one of these in the list is "Joe's Bar & Grill". One of the fields in my mongodb is "type" and it's an array. So now, this particular document will look something like this:

```
{
  id: 'joes-bar-and-grill',
  name: 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
  type: ['bar']
}
```

But then I run another request on the Yelp API on "restaurants", and in this list "Joe's Bar & Grill" shows up again. Instead of inserting a new duplicate document into mongodb, I'd like the existing document to end up looking like this:

```
{
  id: 'joes-bar-and-grill',
  name: 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
  type: ['bar', 'restaurant']
}
```

In addition to this, let's say I run another request again for "bars", and "Joe's Bar & Grill" comes up again. I don't want it to automatically insert "bar" into the `type` array again, if "bar" already exists in its array.

I've tried `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert: true` and a `$push` of new data into the array, but I cannot get it to work at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are using the wrong operator. What you want is the `$addToSet` operator

Comment: Do you know which MongoDB version you are using? There are some new and different update-style methods in the newer versions, so we need to take that into account when answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate`, combined with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) (to make sure that an entry in the array only exists once) and [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) (to allow passing arrays to `$addToSet`):

```
Bar.findOneAndUpdate({ id : 'joes-bar-and-grill' }, {
  id        : 'joes-bar-and-grill',
  name      : 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
  $addToSet : { type : { $each : [ 'restaurant' ] } }
}, { upsert : true })
```

**EDIT**: now that you posted your entire code, the problem becomes more obvious.

For one, I'm not sure if the third and fourth arguments that you're passing to `Location.update()` make sense. As far as I know, the third should be an option *object*, and the fourth an async *function*.

Secondly, it looks like you're just ignoring any update errors.

And lastly, this isn't going to work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < payload.businesses.length; i++) { Location.update(...) }
```

Because `Location.update()` is asynchronous, the `i` variable will get clobbered (you should browse around on SO to find the explanation for that; for example, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754626/asynchronous-loops-in-javascript-node-js)).

You're going to need a library that will provide you with better async support, and preferably one that will also help limiting the number of update queries.

Once such library is [`async`](http://caolan.github.io/async/), and using it, your code would become something like this:

```
const async = require('async');

...

async.eachLimit(payload.businesses, 5, function(business, callback) {
  Location.update({ yelpID : business.id }, {
    name      : business.name,
    latitude  : business.location.latitude,
    longitude : business.location.longitude,
    address1  : business.location.address1,
    address2  : business.location.address2,
    address3  : business.location.address3,
    city      : business.location.city,
    state     : business.location.state,
    zip_code  : business.location.zip_code,
    country   : business.location.country,
    timezone  : 'CST'
    $addToSet : { type : 'bar' }
  }, { upsert : true }, callback);
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('All documents inserted');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as written, because your [update parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) contains both field names and an $addToSet operator; but it's only supposed to contain update operators. Did you mean to put the _id_ and _name_ sections in a $set section?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Mongoose does that automatically (documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update): _"All top level keys which are not atomic operation names are treated as set operations"_). Also, I actually tested this code ;D

Comment: Fair enough so, I wasn't aware of Mongoose using a different syntax.

Comment: I attempted this but nothing is being inserted into the database. No errors, either @robertklep

Comment: @robertklep that worked!! i had done some research on async and i figured it might have something to do with the issue. my background is predominantly php/mysql so I don't have much experience in changing from procedural code, but this has been extremely helpful and informative! thanks you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You may use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.
>
> $addToSet only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the
>   set and does not affect existing duplicate elements. $addToSet does
>   not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set.
>
> If the field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates
>   the array field with the specified value as its element.
>
> If the field is not an array, the operation will fail.

The below solution assumes that on each update, you receive a single type and not an array. If the input document is an array itself, you may use robertklep's solution with `$each` operator

```
db.mycoll.update(
   { "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" },
   {
      $set:{
           name : 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
      },
      $addToSet : { type : 'restaurant' }
   },
   true, false);
```

I have also used [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator.

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified
>   value.
>
> The $set operator expression has the following form:
>
> { $set: { field1: value1, ... } }

Here is the mongo shell output to explain it further :

```
> db.mycoll.find({ "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" });
  // NO RESULT

> db.mycoll.update(
...    { "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" },
...    {
...       $set:{
...            name : 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
...       },
...       $addToSet : { type : 'restaurant' }
...    },
...    true, false);
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e719b4d543c5e30d615d59")
})
 // INSERTED A NEW DOCUMENT AS IT DOES NOT EXIST

> db.mycoll.find({ "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" }); // FINDING THE OBJECT
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e719b4d543c5e30d615d59"), "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill", "name" : "Joe's Bar & Grill", "type" : [ "restaurant" ] }


> db.mycoll.update(
...    { "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" },
...    {
...       $set:{
...            name : 'Joe\'s Bar & Grill',
...       },
...       $addToSet : { type : 'bar' }
...    },
...    true, false);
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
// UPDATING THE DOCUMENT WITH NEW TYPE : "bar"

> db.mycoll.findOne({ "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill" });
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e719b4d543c5e30d615d59"),
    "id" : "joes-bar-and-grill",
    "name" : "Joe's Bar & Grill",
    "type" : [
        "restaurant",
        "bar"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can nest update operators like that; you've got $addToSet contained within the $set section.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thanks for informing. Fixed now.

Comment: but this only updates an existing document, correct? what i need is something that will update if it exists, and insert if it does not.

Comment: @robotsushi it will update if it exists and insert a new document if not already exists. Please try it in your Mongo shell

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I am using this in my script as a mongoose Model. I have updated this post with my code for your review. When I attempt the code you provided I get an error which will also be listed above.