# How to do multiple queries to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am trying to create a table and , insert some values in database with help of PHP script.
While inserting only 1 row , it works fine. An when I try to enter more number of rows , It gives error;

I need to write whole insert statement for every query as I am using an online excel to SQL query converter.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once("connect_to_Mysql.php");
$sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE book (
Book_Index INT,
Book_name VARCHAR(38) CHARACTER SET utf8,
author_name VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
Publisher VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8,
Category INT,
Subcategory VARCHAR(21) CHARACTER SET utf8,
Price INT)";

$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
echo "<h3>Success creating book table</h3>";

$sqlCommand = "
INSERT INTO book VALUES (1,'Concepts of Physics Volume I','hc verma','bharti bhavan','jee','physics',635,'english');
 INSERT INTO book VALUES (2,'PLANE TRIGONOMETRY Part-1','sl loni','arihant publication','jee','math',95,'english');
 INSERT INTO book VALUES (3,'VIT (VELLORE) EDGE SOLVED PAPERS & 10 MOCK        TESTS (2007-2015)','Arihant Experts','arihant publication','vit','all in one',345,'english');
 INSERT INTO book VALUES (4,'A Textbook of Algebra','sk goyal','arihant publication','jee','math',425,'english');
INSERT INTO book VALUES (5,'New Pattern IIT JEE PHYSICS','dc pandey','arihant publication','jee','physics',665,'english');
INSERT INTO book VALUES (6,'Objective Approach to Mathematics','amit m aggrawal','arihant publication','jee','math',710,'english');
INSERT INTO book VALUES (7,'A Complete Success Package for','Experts Compilation','arihant publication','bitsat','all in one',775,'english');
INSERT INTO book VALUES (8,'15 Years'' Solved Papers for AMU Engineering     Entrance Exam','arihant Experts','arihant publication','AMU','all in one',325,'english');
INSERT INTO book VALUES (9,'Solved Papers & 5 Mock Tests for BVP Engineering','arihant Experts','arihant publication','BVP','all in one',365,'english');

";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
echo "<h3>Success populating the pages table with data</h3>";

?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Successful database connection, happy coding!!!
Success creating book table
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds      to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use     near 'INSERT INTO book VALUES (2,'PLANE TRIGONOMETRY Part-1','sl loni','arihant public' at line 2
```

Comment: change your syntax to something more like that found in this prior question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql  essentially `insert into book values (field1, field2, field3), (field1,field2, field3)...`  each new record is represented by a new "set" `(),` last set containing a `;` instead of `,`  and the field list before the values I believe needs to be defined.  Note: this syntax varies by RDBMS.  So this is a mySQL link

Comment: Take advantage of multi-query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: you don't. mysqli doesn't allow multiple queries in a single query() call for security reasons. either use the multi-value extended syntax that mysql offers, or run multiple query() calls.

Comment: @xQbert Yeah, that works fine... but I have my database in excel. And I am using an online excel to sql query converter.

Comment: thing is; are the codes for all the INSERTs being generated by that converter? That...is the question.

Comment: @tarun14110... so you're saying the driver which converts the mySQL syntax to Excel doesn't support multi line insert statements?  A) Find a new driver, B) choose a different Database which supports this method c) use multiple insert statements.  if you're locked in to Excel and driver, C is your only choice.  You may be able to do what Fred -ii suggests, I've not tried it.  ***Excel as a back end database when mySQL is tagged is not something I would have guessed.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysqli_multi_query` instead of `mysqli_query`, that should do it.

```
$query = mysqli_multi_query($db_conx,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: actually, that alone won't do it. The queries would need to be on individual lines. `$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";` as per the manual example. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- semicolons are the query separators, newlines are irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar Alrighty. However, wouldn't the OP have to add spaces before their existing INSERT? Wouldn't that throw a syntax error? Plus, OP is no longer responding, nor do I see a green tick next to the answer here (yet). Edit: OP accepted it.

Comment: mysqli_multi_query() worked smoothly.  Thanks to all

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, you don't need space after semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach could be to split the string with `;` and iterate of each query in the array. Execute all of them one by one..

```
$sqlCommandArray[]=explode(";",$sqlCommand);

for($i=0;$i<count($sqlCommandArray);$i++){
try{
  mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlCommandArray[$i]);
} 
catch(Exception $ex){
  echo "there was an error in executing the queries";
}
}
```

This would do the job without any modifications.

```
 $query = mysqli_multi_query($db_conx,$sqlCommand);
```