# how to insert dynamic form fields into mysql using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form with 3 fields iteno, perno, and description with three textboxes in a row(iteno,perno, description). However a user can click a button and dynamically add another row having the same 3 text boxes(iteno,perno, description). He/she can add as many rows as he/she wants with same set of boxes(iteno,perno, description).

My question is how to insert the same to database using php & mysql
by using foreach loop.

Comment: There's not enough details. Do you insert each yime the user click the button? If so, ajax is the answer. If you submit it somehow, you can do a plain insert of multiple entry with a single mysql request. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the form post you will, I guess, see only one value for each textbox. To submit multiple rows from a single form, you need to define each textbox as an array, then multiple rows will be posted.

```
<input type="text" name="iteno[]" />
```

Now when you process it each post param will be an array that you iterate over.

Comment: @carl, no ,the user add as many rows as h/she wants, once h/she fills the details and submit

Comment: let me try that ad get back to you, thank you

Comment: it give a null in database

Comment: So post your new code and ask a new question please.

Comment: how can i use foreach to insert arrays

Comment: As I said, post your new code and ask a new question. But search first as I am sure this has been asked and answered many many times.