# Inserting multiple rows in 1 query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched about this already on stackoverflow and found this:
[Inserting multiple rows in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)

Sadly when I try this it's not working for me.

when I got a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12'),
('test1', 'test2'),
(1, 2),
(0, 0),
(0, 0);
```

it gives me the following error:

`#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

even when I add the () arround my values like this:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
(('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12'),
('test1', 'test2'),
(1, 2),
(0, 0),
(0, 0));
```

it gives me the following error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

So how can I  solve this problem and add multiple lines with 1 query?

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory. You specified 5 columns but only supplied 2 values per row.

Comment: Oh right, it works the other way arround... I thought I needed to add each value 2 times (if I wanted to add 2 lines). My query isn't build up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12'),
('test1', 'test2'),
(1, 2),
(0, 0),
(0, 0);
```

Fields list has 5 columns where as your values list has only two.

Either remove three from fields list or add three in the columns list.

Solution to this:

Add default values to three remaining value columns:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12', '', '', ''),
('test1', 'test2', '', '', ''),
(1, 2, '', '', ''),
(0, 0, '', '', ''),
(0, 0, '', '', ''),;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
('2016-01-12', 'test1', 1,0,0),
('2016-01-12', 'test2',2,0,0);
```

You have to add the values row wise.

Answer (score 1):

you insert 2 values in more than 2 column, your query can be:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving)
VALUES
(('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12'),
('test1', 'test2'),
(1, 2),
(0, 0),
(0, 0));
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
(('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12', '', '', ''),
('test1', 'test2', '', '', ''),
(1, 2, '', '', ''),
(0, 0, '', '', ''),
(0, 0, '', '', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each set of values should match the number of the columns, so if the remaining 3 fields are supposed to remain empty, just add those to the sets, or fill them up with corresponding values:

```
INSERT INTO productielijn1
(Datum, Productieomschrijving, Aantal, AantalGemaakt, Verschil)
VALUES
('2016-01-12', '2016-01-12','','',''),
('test1', 'test2','','',''),
(1, 2,'','',''),
(0, 0,'','',''),
(0, 0,'','','');
```