# Insert multiple rows to database without using looping

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

I have following psql query to insert data to database

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO kart_user (custid,token,cycle,userid,proxyid,salesrepid,users,buyer,salesrep,validfrom,validto,discount,category,ratioOnly,proxy,notified) ""VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")
result = self.cur.execute(sql,data)
self.dbconn.commit()
return result
```

Now, the problem I facing ,in some case data may contain multiple rows.in this case how can i rewrite my code. 
Note: I don't like to use for loop for data iteration ,please suggest better way to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql) Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`executemany()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) would help:

```
result = self.cur.executemany(sql, data)
```

`data` in this case should be a list of lists or a list of tuples.